# How to pass data between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im trying to pass data between two fragmens in my program. Its just a simple string that is stored in the List. The List is made public in fragments A, and when the user clicks on a list item, I need it to show up in fragment B. The content provider only seems to support ID's, so that will not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149802/how-to-transfer-some-data-to-another-fragment

this may help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Pass data(extras) to a fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392261/android-pass-dataextras-to-a-fragment)

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 25):

Why don't you use a Bundle. From your first fragment, here's how to set it up:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then in your second Fragment, retrieve the data using:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
int myInt = bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue);
```

Bundle has put methods for lots of data types. Please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

Answer (score 21):

If you use Roboguice you can use the EventManager in Roboguice to pass data around without using the Activity as an interface. This is quite clean IMO.

If you're not using Roboguice you can use Otto too as a event bus: http://square.github.com/otto/

**Update 20150909:** You can also use Green Robot Event Bus or even RxJava now too. Depends on your use case.

Comment: I wholeheartedly second what Donn says here. Use a bus and untangle all this stuff and stop writing listeners and callbacks manually. Otto FTW.

Comment: If you dont want to use RoboGuice, you can use Otto by Square. I use Otto quite a bit now and its AWESOME. https://github.com/square/otto

Comment: If you like Otto, you might also appreciate EventBus, which additionally offers thread handling. https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: I can see the event bus strategy working if both fragments are visible at the same time, but how would this work if Fragment A (Let's say it is a ListFragment) takes up the whole screen and selecting a List item launches Fragment B which also takes up the whole screen. AFAIK, the event bus pattern has each fragment registering/unregistering in onResume/onPause so I'm not sure how I'd apply this.

Comment: @Matthew if thats the case you'll need to pass them around in bundles between activities which can then inject the data into them at runtime.

Comment: @DonnFelker I am in the situation that Matthew described and I am still not seeing it very clear. How would it work with just one activity and several fragments? I fear I will end up with a monster Activity :/

Comment: You could also implement the MVP Pattern (passive view or supervising controller) from Fowler. This is how a lot of separation of concerns problems are addressed. http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html and http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html

Answer (score 17):

From the `Fragment` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html):

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for example to change the content based on a user event. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

So I suggest you have look on the [basic fragment training docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) in the documentation. They're pretty comprehensive with an example and a walk-through guide.

Answer (score 12):

So lets say you have Activity AB that controls Frag A and Fragment B. 
Inside Fragment A you need an interface that Activity AB can implement. 
In the sample android code, they have:

`private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;`

/*A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item selections.
*/

```
public interface Callbacks {
/*Callback for when an item has been selected. */    
      public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

/*A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity. */    
private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    }
};
```

The Callback interface is put inside one of your Fragments (let’s say Fragment A). I think the purpose of this Callbacks interface is like a nested class inside Frag A which any Activity can implement. So if Fragment A was a TV, the CallBacks is the TV Remote (interface) that allows Fragment A to be used by Activity AB. I may be wrong about the detail because I'm a noob but I did get my program to work perfectly on all screen sizes and this is what I used.

So inside Fragment A, we have:
(I took this from Android’s Sample programs)

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
// Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
// fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
//mCallbacks.onItemSelected( PUT YOUR SHIT HERE. int, String, etc.);
//mCallbacks.onItemSelected (Object);
}
```

And inside Activity AB we override the onItemSelected method:

```
public class AB extends FragmentActivity implements ItemListFragment.Callbacks {
//...
@Override
//public void onItemSelected (CATCH YOUR SHIT HERE) {
//public void onItemSelected (Object obj) {
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    //Pass Data to Fragment B. For example:
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putString(“FragmentB_package”, id);
    FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();
    }
```

So inside Activity AB, you basically throwing everything into a Bundle and passing it to B. If u are not sure how to use a Bundle, look the class up.

I am basically going by the sample code that Android provided. The one with the DummyContent stuff. When you make a new Android Application Package, it's the one titled MasterDetailFlow.

Answer (score 8):

1- The first way is define an interface

```
public interface OnMessage{
    void sendMessage(int fragmentId, String message);
}

public interface OnReceive{
    void onReceive(String message);
}
```

2- In you activity implement OnMessage interface

```
public class MyActivity implements OnMessage {
   ...
   @Override
   public void sendMessage(int fragmentId, String message){
       Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(fragmentId);
       ((OnReceive) fragment).sendMessage();
   }
}
```

3- In your fragment implement OnReceive interface

```
public class MyFragment implements OnReceive{
    ...
    @Override
    public void onReceive(String message){
        myTextView.setText("Received message:" + message);
    }
}
```

This is the boilerplate version of handling message passing between fragments.

Another way of handing data passage between fragments are by using an event bus.

1- Register/unregister to an event bus

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

2- Define an event class

```
public class Message{
    public final String message;

    public Message(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

3- Post this event in anywhere in your application

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new Message("hello world"));
```

4- Subscribe to that event to receive it in your Fragment

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessage(Message event){
    mytextview.setText(event.message);
}
```

For more [details, use cases, and an example project](http://gunhansancar.com/ease-communication-between-activities-fragments-services/) about the event bus pattern.

Comment: Please [don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*.

Answer (score 3):

IN my case i had to **send the data backwards from FragmentB->FragmentA hence Intents was not an option as the fragment would already be initialised** All though all of the **above answers** sounds good it takes a **lot of boiler plate code to implement**, so i went with a much **simpler approach** of using **LocalBroadcastManager**, it exactly does the above said but without alll the nasty boilerplate code. An example is shared below.

**In Sending Fragment(Fragment B)**

```
public class FragmentB {

    private void sendMessage() {
      Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
      intent.putExtra("message", "your message");
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
 }
```

**And in the Message to be Received Fragment(FRAGMENT A)**

```
  public class FragmentA {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      ...

      // Register receiver
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver,
          new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
    }

//    This will be called whenever an Intent with an action named "custom-event-name" is broadcasted.
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
      }
    };
}
```

Hope it helps someone

Comment: so I used this code and it seems like onReceive is getting called twice no Idea why.

Comment: well never registerReciver inside a fragment as it will be registered twice for some reason

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how the fragment is structured. If you can have some of the methods on the Fragment Class B static and also the target TextView object static, you can call the method directly on Fragment Class A. This is better than a listener as the method is performed instantaneously, and we don't need to have an additional task that performs listening throughout the activity. See example below:

```
Fragment_class_B.setmyText(String yourstring);
```

On Fragment B you can have the method defined as:

```
public static void setmyText(final String string) {
myTextView.setText(string);
}
```

Just don't forget to have myTextView set as static on Fragment B, and properly import the Fragment B class on Fragment A.

Just did the procedure on my project recently and it worked. Hope that helped.

Comment: That'll work (well, until the fragment is destroyed and recreated, think device rotation) but you're tightly coupling fragments; the dependent fragment (let's call it 'X') has a hardwired dependency in its code on the other fragment ('Y'). Going via the parent activity is much neater because you can leave it to the activity to decide where to get the data from. For example on a phone your activity might use fragments X and Y, but on a tablet you might decide to use X and Z. Better to let the Activity (which knows what fragments exist) act as middle man and connect to Y or Z as appropriate.

Comment: what about to call the Asyntask from this method

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a similar project and I guess my code may help in the above situation

Here is the overview of what i'm doing

My project Has two fragments Called "**FragmentA**" and **"FragmentB**"

-**FragmentA** Contains  one list View,when you click an item in **FragmentA** It's INDEX is passed to **FragmentB** using Communicator interface

- The design pattern is totally based on the concept of java interfaces that says
  "**interface reference variables can refer to a subclass object"**
- Let **MainActivity** implement the interface provided by **fragmentA**(otherwise we can't make interface reference variable to point to MainActivity)
- In the below code communicator object is made to refer to  **MainActivity's** object by using "**setCommunicator(Communicatot c)**" method present in **fragmentA**.
- I'm  triggering  **respond()** method of interface from **FrgamentA** using the MainActivity's reference.

  Interface communcator is defined inside fragmentA, this is to provide least access previlage to **communicator** interface.

below is my complete working code

**FragmentA.java**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

ListView list;
Communicator communicater;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenta, container,false);
}

public void setCommunicator(Communicator c){
    communicater=c;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    communicater=(Communicator) getActivity();
    list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvModularListView);
    ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.items, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int index, long arg3) {
communicater.respond(index);

}

public interface Communicator{
    public void respond(int index);
}
```

}

**fragmentB.java**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

ListView list;
Communicator communicater;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenta, container,false);
}

public void setCommunicator(Communicator c){
    communicater=c;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    communicater=(Communicator) getActivity();
    list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvModularListView);
    ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.items, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int index, long arg3) {
communicater.respond(index);

}

public interface Communicator{
    public void respond(int index);
}

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FragmentA.Communicator {
FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentA fragA=(FragmentA) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmenta);
    fragA.setCommunicator(this);


}

@Override
public void respond(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

FragmentB FragB=(FragmentB) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentb);
FragB.changetext(i);
}



}
```

Comment: Posted FragmentB code is same as FragmentA.  Please correct.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basically Implement the interface to communicate between Activity and fragment.

1) Main activty

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SendFragment.StartCommunication
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void setComm(String msg) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
DisplayFragment mDisplayFragment = (DisplayFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
if(mDisplayFragment != null && mDisplayFragment.isInLayout())
{
mDisplayFragment.setText(msg);
}
else
{
Toast.makeText(this, "Error Sending Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
}
```

2) sender fragment (fragment-to-Activity)

```
public class SendFragment extends Fragment
{
StartCommunication mStartCommunicationListner;
String msg = "hi";
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
View mView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.send_fragment, container);
final EditText mEditText = (EditText)mView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Button mButton = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
msg = mEditText.getText().toString();
sendMessage();
}
});
return mView;
}

interface StartCommunication
{
public void setComm(String msg);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onAttach(activity);
if(activity instanceof StartCommunication)
{
mStartCommunicationListner = (StartCommunication)activity;
}
else
throw new ClassCastException();

}

public void sendMessage()
{
mStartCommunicationListner.setComm(msg);
}

}
```

3) receiver fragment (Activity-to-fragment)

```
    public class DisplayFragment extends Fragment
{
View mView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
mView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.display_frgmt_layout, container);
return mView;
}

void setText(String msg)
{
TextView mTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
mTextView.setText(msg);
}

}
```

I used this link for the same solution, I hope somebody will find it usefull.
Very simple and basic example.

http://infobloggall.com/2014/06/22/communication-between-activity-and-fragments/

Answer (score 1):

`getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener` is the 2020 way of doing this. Your only limitation is to use a bundle to pass the data. Check out the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/pass-data-between) for more info and examples.

Some other ways

- Call to `getActivity()` and cast it to the shared activity between your fragments, then use it as a bridge to pass the data. This solution is highly not recommended because of the cupelling it requires between the activity and the fragments, but it used to be the popular way of doing this back in the KitKat days...
- Use callbacks. Any events mechanism will do. This would be a Java vanilla solution. The benefit over `FragmentManager` is that it's not limited to Bundles. The downside, however, is that you may run into edge cases bugs where you mess up the activity life cycle and get exceptions like `IllegalStateException` when the fragment manager is in the middle of saving state or the activity were destroyed. Also, it does not support cross-processing communication.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment class A

```
public class CountryListFragment extends ListFragment{

    /** List of countries to be displayed in the ListFragment */

    ListFragmentItemClickListener ifaceItemClickListener;   

    /** An interface for defining the callback method */
    public interface ListFragmentItemClickListener {
    /** This method will be invoked when an item in the ListFragment is clicked */
    void onListFragmentItemClick(int position);
}   

/** A callback function, executed when this fragment is attached to an activity */  
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try{
        /** This statement ensures that the hosting activity implements ListFragmentItemClickListener */
        ifaceItemClickListener = (ListFragmentItemClickListener) activity;          
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(activity.getBaseContext(), "Exception",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Fragment Class B

```
public class CountryDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /** Inflating the layout country_details_fragment_layout to the view object v */
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.country_details_fragment_layout, null);

    /** Getting the textview object of the layout to set the details */ 
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.country_details);      

    /** Getting the bundle object passed from MainActivity ( in Landscape   mode )  or from 
     *  CountryDetailsActivity ( in Portrait Mode )  
     * */
    Bundle b = getArguments();

    /** Getting the clicked item's position and setting corresponding  details in the textview of the detailed fragment */
    tv.setText("Details of " + Country.name[b.getInt("position")]);     

    return v;
    }

}
```

Main Activity class for passing data between fragments

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ListFragmentItemClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}


/** This method will be executed when the user clicks on an item in the listview */
@Override
public void onListFragmentItemClick(int position) {

    /** Getting the orientation ( Landscape or Portrait ) of the screen */
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;


    /** Landscape Mode */
    if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ){
        /** Getting the fragment manager for fragment related operations */
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        /** Getting the fragmenttransaction object, which can be used to add, remove or replace a fragment */
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        /** Getting the existing detailed fragment object, if it already exists. 
         *  The fragment object is retrieved by its tag name  *
         */
Fragment prevFrag = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("in.wptrafficanalyzer.country.details");

        /** Remove the existing detailed fragment object if it exists */
        if(prevFrag!=null)
    fragmentTransaction.remove(prevFrag);           

        /** Instantiating the fragment CountryDetailsFragment */
  CountryDetailsFragment fragment = new CountryDetailsFragment();

        /** Creating a bundle object to pass the data(the clicked item's   position) from the activity to the fragment */ 
        Bundle b = new Bundle();

        /** Setting the data to the bundle object */
        b.putInt("position", position);

        /** Setting the bundle object to the fragment */
        fragment.setArguments(b);           

        /** Adding the fragment to the fragment transaction */
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.detail_fragment_container,   fragment,"in.wptrafficanalyzer.country.details");

        /** Adding this transaction to backstack */
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

        /** Making this transaction in effect */
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }else{          /** Portrait Mode or Square mode */
        /** Creating an intent object to start the CountryDetailsActivity */
        Intent intent = new Intent("in.wptrafficanalyzer.CountryDetailsActivity");

        /** Setting data ( the clicked item's position ) to this intent */
        intent.putExtra("position", position);

        /** Starting the activity by passing the implicit intent */
        startActivity(intent);          
      }
    }
 }
```

Detailde acitivity class

```
public class CountryDetailsActivity extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /** Setting the layout for this activity */
    setContentView(R.layout.country_details_activity_layout);

    /** Getting the fragment manager for fragment related operations */
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    /** Getting the fragmenttransaction object, which can be used to add, remove or replace a fragment */
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransacton = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    /** Instantiating the fragment CountryDetailsFragment */
    CountryDetailsFragment detailsFragment = new CountryDetailsFragment();

    /** Creating a bundle object to pass the data(the clicked item's position) from the activity to the fragment */
    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    /** Setting the data to the bundle object from the Intent*/
    b.putInt("position", getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0));

    /** Setting the bundle object to the fragment */
    detailsFragment.setArguments(b);

    /** Adding the fragment to the fragment transaction */
    fragmentTransacton.add(R.id.country_details_fragment_container, detailsFragment);       

    /** Making this transaction in effect */
    fragmentTransacton.commit();

    }
}
```

Array Of Contries

```
public class Country {

/** Array of countries used to display in CountryListFragment */
static String name[] = new String[] {
        "India",
        "Pakistan",
        "Sri Lanka",
        "China",
        "Bangladesh",
        "Nepal",
        "Afghanistan",
        "North Korea",
        "South Korea",
        "Japan",
        "Bhutan"
};
}
```

For More Details visit this link [http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/itemclick-handler-for-listfragment-in-android/]. There are full example ..

Answer (score -2):

Basically here we are dealing with communication between Fragments. Communication between fragments can never be directly possible. It involves activity under the context of which both the fragments are created.

You need to create an interface in the sending fragment and implement the interface in the activity which will reprieve the message and transfer to the receiving fragment.