# How to transfer some data to another Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to transfer some data to another `Fragment` likewise it was done with `extras` for `intents`?

Comment: I try to answer this question @[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27626004/4249919). I hope t works.

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 526, accepted):

Use a `Bundle`. Here's an example:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Bundle has put methods for lots of data types.  See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)

Then in your `Fragment`, retrieve the data (e.g. in **`onCreate()`** method) with:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
        int myInt = bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanx for your answer but do we need to implement anything??like Serializable or Parcelable??

Comment: No, you do not need to implement any classes.

Comment: Might want to add a check to see that bundle != Null before you attempt to get anything out of it?

Comment: And if you have an existing fragment in memory?

Comment: this is code not working ,not redirecting activity to fragment with data

Answer (score 48):

To extend the previous answer even more, like Ankit was saying, for complex objects you need to implement Serializable. For example, for the simple object:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2163051469151804394L;
    private int id;
    private String created;
}
```

In your FromFragment:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable(TAG_MY_CLASS, myClass);
Fragment toFragment = new ToFragment();
toFragment.setArguments(args);
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.body, toFragment, TAG_TO_FRAGMENT)
    .addToBackStack(TAG_TO_FRAGMENT).commit();
```

in your ToFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    MyClass myClass = (MyClass) args
        .getSerializable(TAG_MY_CLASS);
```

Comment: @Sameera I usually just put a string with my fragment class, i.e. if I have class MyFragmentIMGoingTo.java then my TAG_TO_FRAGMENT = "MyFragmentIMGoingTo";

Comment: Better use Parcelable as google recommended it as more optimized serialization technique for android operating system.

Answer (score 17):

getArguments() is returning null because "Its doesn't get anything"

Try this code to handle this situation

```
if(getArguments()!=null)
{
int myInt = getArguments().getInt(key, defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanx for your answer but do we need to implement anything??like Serializable or Parcelable??

Comment: are you sure?because i had to implement Serializable/ Parcelable when i was passing complex data  between a fragment and an activity by using intent ......

Comment: i tried with simple values only. No idea about Serializable or Parcelable sorry

Comment: It should be a comment not answer !!

Answer (score 14):

**Complete code of passing data using fragment to fragment**

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment(); // replace your custom fragment class 
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                bundle.putString("key","value"); // use as per your need
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(viewID,fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**In custom fragment class**

```
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle = getArguments();
mBundle.getString(key);  // key must be same which was given in first fragment
```

Comment: @Hoo : please specify your question what you want to ask

Comment: can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983033/pass-data-to-another-fragment-by-swipe-view-with-tab-android-studio-not-button

Answer (score 6):

Just to extend previous answers - it could help someone. If your `getArguments()` returns `null`, put it to `onCreate()` method and not to constructor of your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int index = getArguments().getInt("index");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using kotlin then you can pass `bundle` as

```
val fragment = YourFragment()
val bundle = Bundle().apply {
    putInt("someInt", 5)
    putString("someString", "Hello")
}
fragment.arguments = bundle
```

And get these values in `YourFragment`'s `onCreate` as

```
this.arguments?.let {
    val someInt    = it.getInt("someInt", someDefaultInt)
    val someString = it.getString("someString", someDefaultString)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using graph for navigation between fragments you can do this: From fragment A:

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(KEY, yourObject);
    Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.fragment, bundle);
```

To fragment B:

```
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    object = (Object) bundle.getSerializable(KEY);
```

Of course your object must implement Serializable

Comment: The best and easy answer

Answer (score 2):

This is how you use bundle:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("id", id);
Fragment frag= new Fragment();
frag.setArguments(b);
```

retrieve value from bundle:

```
 bundle = getArguments();
 if (bundle != null) {
    id = bundle.getInt("id");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            First Fragment Sending String To Next Fragment
            public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
                    private Button Add;
                    private EditText edt;
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
                    FragClass1 fragClass1;


                    @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                        Add= (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnNext);
                        edt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

                        Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                fragClass1=new FragClass1();
                                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();

                                fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                                fragClass1.setArguments(bundle);
                                bundle.putString("hello",edt.getText().toString());
                                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_main,fragClass1,"");
                                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
         Next Fragment to fetch the string.
            public class FragClass1 extends Fragment {
                  EditText showFrag1;


                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_frag1,null);
                        showFrag1= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtText);
                        Bundle bundle=getArguments();
                        String a=getArguments().getString("hello");//Use This or The Below Commented Code
                        showFrag1.setText(a);
                        //showFrag1.setText(String.valueOf(bundle.getString("hello")));
                        return view;
                    }
                }
    I used Frame Layout easy to use.
    Don't Forget to Add Background color or else fragment will overlap.
This is for First Fragment.
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:context="com.example.sumedh.fragmentpractice1.MainActivity">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/BtnNext"/>
    </FrameLayout>


Xml for Next Fragment.
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edtText"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Explain your answer? code without any explanation will not do much help

Comment: i have written code in a flow so its could be understood..... Passing data From Main Activity to FragClass1 with use of bundle.

Answer (score 1):

From Activity Class:

*Send the data using bundle arguments to the fragment and load the fragment*

```
   Fragment fragment = new myFragment();
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("pName", personName);
   bundle.putString("pEmail", personEmail);
   bundle.putString("pId", personId);
   fragment.setArguments(bundle);

   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    fragment).commit();
```

From myFragment Class:

*Get the arguments from the bundle and set them to xml*

```
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    String personName = arguments.getString("pName");
    String personEmail = arguments.getString("pEmail");
    String personId = arguments.getString("pId");

    nameTV = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    emailTV = v.findViewById(R.id.email);
    idTV = v.findViewById(R.id.id);

    nameTV.setText("Name: "+ personName);
    emailTV.setText("Email: "+ personEmail);
    idTV.setText("ID: "+ personId);
```

Comment: Please read the question again, It is about fragment to fragment

Answer (score 0):

Your input fragment

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment  {


    EditText etext;
    Button btn;
    String etex;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondfragment, container, false);
        etext = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
        return v;
    }

    View.OnClickListener mClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            etex = etext.getText().toString();
            FragmentTransaction transection = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Viewfragment mfragment = new Viewfragment();
            //using Bundle to send data
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("textbox", etex);
            mfragment.setArguments(bundle); //data being send to SecondFragment
            transection.replace(R.id.frame, mfragment);
            transection.isAddToBackStackAllowed();
            transection.addToBackStack(null);
            transection.commit();

        }
    };



}
```

your view fragment

```
public class Viewfragment extends Fragment {

    TextView txtv;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewfrag,container,false);
        txtv = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        Bundle bundle=getArguments();
        txtv.setText(String.valueOf(bundle.getString("textbox")));
        return v;
    }


}
```