# How to get the object of fragmentA from fragmentB in a Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

### What i have

- I have an activity
- `MainActivity.java` here in this activity I have a
  fragment(`MainFragment.java`)
- In `MainFragment.java` I have two child fragments `ChildOne.java` and
  `ChildTwo.java`
- I have a editText in `ChildOne.java`

### What I am trying to do:

- I need to get the value in the editText of `ChildOne.java` from
  `ChildTwo.java`
- how to achieve this !

Comment: why don't you use that `EditText` in your activity? what do you want to do with that?

Comment: are you showing both the child fragment at the same time? if not this can be done

Comment: 1- define one public method in childTwo,2- define an interface in childOne , 3- implement that in your activity , 4- add watch listener for your editText on childOne , 5- in that call your interface method and in that method call your public method on childTwo

Comment: are you showing two child fragment at same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in multiple ways, but I'll give you one supposing that both Fragments are displayed at the same time.

In your `ChildTwo` use `getParentFragment` to get `MainFragment`.

```
MainFragment parent = (MainFragment) getParentFragment();
String edit_text_value = parent.getChildOneText();
```

In your `MainFragment` you need a reference object to your `ChildOne` fragment.

```
public String getChildOneText()
{
     return mFirstFragment.getEditTextValue();
}
```

Finally in your `ChildOne` fragment create a method to return your `EditText`.

```
public String getEditTextValue()
{
   return my_edit.getText().toString();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You may create one function in mainActivity and a variable that holds the value in there. And call that function when you want to save the data of editText, And can create a function to get the data in MainActivity as well. Call those functions like this -

`((Home) getActivity()).shareData("example string");
 ((Home) getActivity()).receiveData("example string");`

May check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23250795/609782) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12423910/609782)