# How to transfer value from one fragment to another fragment

Tags: android, bundle, fragment

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149802/how-to-transfer-some-data-to-another-fragment)
I do not understand this example.
How to apply in my program

I try to write In my program

General use that I can.
But replaced fragment.
I do not know how to use.

Pass the value of the object.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.templistmune, container, false);
FragmentManager DS2 = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction DSE2 = DS2.beginTransaction();
    Fragment DF2 = DS2.findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout4);
    if (DF2 == null) {
        String title = "Fragment A";
        templistview2 usermune = new templistview2(title);
        DSE2.add(R.id.frameLayout4, usermune);
        DSE2.addToBackStack(null);
        DSE2.commit();   
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String SAS="50";
        bundle.putString("ST", SAS);
        DF2.setArguments(bundle);
////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
```

The pick value the object
templistview2.java

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.templistmune2, container, false);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    String myST = bundle.getString("ST", SAS);
 ///////////////////Error SAS cannot be resolved to a variable  /////////////////



        return view;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only adding adding the `Bundle` when `DF2` is null... so your program will either crash with a `NullPointerException` somewhere along the line or run but not have the `Bundle` passed.

So place

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    String SAS="50";
    bundle.putString("ST", SAS);
    DF2.setArguments(bundle);
```

outside the if structure.