# How to pass data from one fragment to another?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

```
startActivity(new Intent(SecondScreen.this,FragmentOne.class).
putExtra("key", VideoFullUrl));
```

And in FragmentOne.class  which extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment

```
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String   url = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");//here showing compilation error "cannot resolve method getIntent "
   //somecode....
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments)

Answer (score 3):

Fragment to Fragment set and get Argument:

Start Activity :

```
 int friendId = 2; //value to pass as extra 
 i = new Intent(firstActivity, SecondActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("friendsID", friendId);
 firstActivity.startActivity(i);
```

SecondActivity:

```
 Fragment_A mFragment_A = new Fragment_A();
 mFragment_A.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
```

Fragment_A:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String Item = getArguments().getString("friendsID");
bundle.putInt("friendsID", Integer.parseInt(Item));

// code

Fragment_B mFragment_B = new Fragment_B();
mFragment_B.setArguments(bundle);
```

Fragment_B:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
int value = bundle.getInt("friendsID");

Log.e("value Fragment get Argument ", "friendsID :" + value);
```

this work for me,try this may be this sample help you.

Comment: Please mark it as answer. If your problem is solved