# How to use an alert dialog to search for an address in google maps api v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-alertdialog, google-maps-api-2, geocode

I've made an `AlertDialog` with an `EditText`, and I want that when the user clicks on 'Buscar' (positiveButton) the map shows a `Marker` in the address entered on the `AlertDialog`. So I think I need to pass the data from this `EditText` to the `MapFragment` in order to use the `Geocoder` with that data.

Here's my `mainActivity.java` with the `AlertDialog`:

```
package com.example.alex.testing_map;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private String location = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer);

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.syncState();

    Fragment fragment = new MapFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.frame_content, fragment);
    ft.commit();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.add_item:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddMail.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.search:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Dirección");

            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            builder.setView(input);

            builder.setPositiveButton("Buscar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  location = input.getText().toString();

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;

}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.mapa:
            fragment = new MapFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft1.replace(R.id.frame_content, fragment);
            ft1.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            break;
        case R.id.help:
            fragment = new Help();
            FragmentTransaction ft2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft2.replace(R.id.frame_content, fragment);
            ft2.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(item.getTitle());
            break;
        case R.id.about:
            fragment = new About();
            FragmentTransaction ft3 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft3.replace(R.id.frame_content, fragment);
            ft3.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(item.getTitle());
            break;
        case R.id.rate:
            Intent face = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            face.setData(Uri.parse("fb://profile/" + "100000914715145"));
            startActivity(face);
            break;
        default:
            return true;

    }


    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}


}
```

And my `MapFragment.java`:

```
package com.example.alex.testing_map;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;



public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {


private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, viewGroup, false);
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    transaction.replace(R.id.mapView, fragment);
    transaction.commit();

    fragment.getMapAsync(this);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        } else {
        }
    }

    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);


    // Primer poso les coordenades i estableixo els punts (numerats amb lletres en castellà)
    // i després afegeixo els marcadors, posant de localització
    // el nom dels punts definits amb anterioritat

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    LatLng p1 = new LatLng(41.39355, 2.15473);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(p1).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pointer_bici1)));
   mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 18));


}

}
```

Comment: the best solution for your problem is https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker#introduction

Comment: do you know how to get latlog of an address ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand what you are trying to do, the `AlertDialog` you are showing is like a search dialog where you put in the address query and when the ***Buscar*** button is clicked, you want it to be sent to the `MapFragment`, where it will be used by your `Geocoder`.

To put it simply, the only issue you have is passing the `location` value from the `EditText` to the `MapFragment`. Looked around the community and found this answer on [How to pass data from Activity to Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16036693/6124253) by using `setArguments()`, like so:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(key, value); // preferred key and the location string you want
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then receive it in the `Fragment` like so:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          String strtext=getArguments().getString("message"); // replace "message" with the key you used.

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    }
```

You can also use a listener, if you want.