# Fragment getArguments() Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, bundle

Almost new to the Android world, I'm having an issue passing parameters between fragments. I need it to set the id of a particular tab of a tab navigation menu.

In my *MainActivity.java* I'm creating a new instance of my *TabFragment* and then starting the transaction like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    ...
    Fragment fragment = TabFragment.newInstance(0);
    fragmentTransaction(mFragmentManager, fragment);
    ...
}
```

where

```
private void fragmentTransaction(FragmentManager mFragmentManager, Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, fragment).commit();
}
```

(I incapsulated it in a method 'cause I need that in other places, too.)

In my TabFragment.java I've written the usual newInstance() method like this:

```
public static TabFragment newInstance(int position) {
    Log.d("POSITION", "newInstance: " + position);
    TabFragment fragment = new TabFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);

    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}
```

The problem is that, staying in TabFragment.java, my getArguments() call is giving back an empty pointer, 'cause it looks like my savedInstanceState is empty too.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    int position;
    try {
        position = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        position = -1;
    }
    Log.d("BUNDLE", "position: " + position);

    int position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);

    ...
}
```

The code is crashing at getArguments().
Commenting that line, I discovered through the exception-catch that the Bundle is empty (position = -1).

Any hint about what I'm making wrong?
I've looked around for similar cases, but I can't apply those solutions to my code.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can follow these steps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments

Comment: I almost always do a null check on `getIntent()` in Activities and `getArguments()` in Fragments, but I don't see anything wrong with what you have (minus catching the NullPointerException... just check if the value is null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I may have fixed it.

I just put

```
position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
```

inside of my try-catch instead of using

```
position = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
```

Now my onCreateView() looks like this, and everything is working.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    int position;

    try {
        position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        position = -1;
    }

    Log.d("BUNDLE", "position: " + position);

    ...
}
```

Hope it will help whoever having my same problem.
Fragments are not as easy as it may look like.

Comment: For cleaner code, you could forget the try catch and do `int position = -1; Bundle arguments = getArguments(); if (arguments != null) { ... }`

Comment: Thank you.
Just a thing: why not having try - catches lets the code being cleaner?

Comment: NullPointerExceptions, in particular, should definitely not need catched because an if statement is all that's needed, plus proper conditional checking actually runs faster if you time the code execution

Answer (score 2):

Send data with Fragment

```
    try {
         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
         bundle.putString("key","value");    // data that you want to send
         LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment(); // Fragment that you want to call
         fragment.setArguments(bundle);
         FragmentTransaction fts = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         fts.replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragment);
         fts.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
         fts.commit();
     }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Receive data with Bundle in other Fragment

```
try {
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      String data = bundle.getString("key");  // Receive data through key
    }
     catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the `getArguments` in the `onActivityCreated` instead. Your code should be something like this:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

 Bundle arguments = getArguments();
 int position = arguments.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
 ...
}
```

I hope this helps you. Give this a try and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is shown below

Call your fragment like this

```
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container, MyMeetings.newInstance("**YOUR DATA**"), "TAG OF FRAGMENT").commit();
```

**R.id.main_container** is my Frame Layout

Now inside your Fragment do this

```
  public static MyMeetings newInstance(String data) {
        MyMeetings fragment = new MyMeetings();


        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("data", data);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String data = getArguments().getString("data");

    }
```

String data  contains your passed data