# pass data from one fragment to multiple fragment in sliding tab layout

Tags: android

I have multiple fragments in sliding tab layout. i want to pass data from 1st tab to other tab. please provide code. while passing data tab should swipe from 1st tab to 2nd tab. please help me. thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763977/how-do-i-pass-a-custom-object-to-a-list-in-a-different-fragment/54764097#54764097 check this out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42870193/9060917  check this

Comment: You can do it with an interface. http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/02/android-communicating-between-viewpager.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass data to another fragment by swipe view with tab android studio,not button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983033/pass-data-to-another-fragment-by-swipe-view-with-tab-android-studio-not-button)

Comment: @SalmanKhan i'm not getting

Comment: Where are you getting stuck @PrithamBnr?

Comment: created custom object class. how to pass my edit text values to that. and how to retrieve in fragment b

Comment: You can make your model class singleton so that on tab change you save that data to your singleton model class and then you can get that on last tab. Make  sure to make your singleton class empty on last tab button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering using **ViewModel** (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)
(https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components)

**First,** Open the **ROOT build.gradle** file for your project (not the ones for your app or module) and add the google() repository as shown below:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Then,** in your **APP MODULE build.gradle** just simply Add this Library to your Gradle then you can Start Using **ViewModel** in your project:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0" // Its Version May Vary
```

To use **ViewModel** :

1. Create **ViewModel Class** and Define that Data you wanted to Pass

   ```
   public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {  
      // Assume you wanted to Pass the Data of 'name' from 1st Tab to 2nd Tab 
      String name = "";

      void resetData() { // Function that will Reset the Data
          name= "";
      }
   }
   ```

**Let's say 1st Tab is FragmentA, 2nd Tab is FragmentB and you wanted to Pass the 'name' Data when you Swipe from 1st Tab to 2nd Tab**

2. Now, In **FragmentA** you can **Set** the 'name' Data of **ViewModel** before you pass the data to **FragmentB**

   ```
   public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

   private MyViewModel  myViewModel ;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // MUST Initialize your ViewModel 
       myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
   }

   protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();

       // You can Set your Value anywhere, Let Set the Value at onStart as an Example
       // Set your Name Data to "Pritham Bnr"
       myViewModel.name= "Pritham Bnr"
   }
   }
   ```

**Note:** Whenever you wanted to Set the 'name' Data of the ViewModel, just use code of `myViewModel.name= "Value you want to Set"`

3. Now you can get the 'name' data from the ViewModel in FragmentB When you Swipe from 1st Tab **(FragmentA)** to 2nd Tab **(FragmentB)**

   ```
   public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

   private MyViewModel  myViewModel ;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // MUST Initialize your ViewModel 
       myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
   }

   protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();

       // You can Get your Value anywhere by call "myViewModel.name", Let Get the Value at onStart as an Example
       // Using Toast to Display the 'name' Data pass from FragmentA using ViewModel
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), myViewModel.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   // for Example, If you want Clear the Data when Swipe Back to FragmentA, you can call resetData() function of the ViewModel
   // Let say we Clear the Data when the Fragment onStop() as you Swipe back to FragmentA
   // This is Optional, just an Example Telling you how to Reset the Data if you want to
   protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();

       // Reset Data when Screen is Being Swipe to FragmentA
       // After Call this function, the ViewModel previous Data of "Pritham Bnr" will be Reset and become "" empty value.
       // So FragmentA now will get "" Data from the ViewModel
       myViewModel.destroyViewModelData();
   }
   }
   ```

**Note:** Whenever you wanted to Get the 'name' Data of the ViewModel, just use code of `myViewModel.name`

**ViewModel** not only can Store String, Int, Double, etc DataType, it can also store **Object** which is very helpful when **Passing Large Amount of Data** from Fragment to Fragment.

This is one of the Simple Way to **Pass Data from Fragment to Fragment**.

Hope this would help, Thank you.

Comment: but i dint understand kotlin. will u provide it in java

Comment: please help me. i cant implement

Comment: Added more Details to my Answer, Check the Top Paragraph. @PrithamBnr

Comment: i ll accept your answer. my target compile sdk version is 26. so i cant use it