# Send data from fragment to fragment using Tab Layout with Swipeable Views in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created a Tab Layout with Swipeable Views.
I'm trying to pass a string from fragment 
to Fragment Thank you in Advance
Details_customer.java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
public class Details_customer extends AppCompatActivity implements   Cust_Details_basic.FragmentDataListener {
SharedPreferences login_pref, IP;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;//For Loading activity..
Bundle dataBundle;
/**
 * The {@link PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_customer);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}


@Override
public void onFragmentDataUpdated(Bundle dataBundle)
{
    this.dataBundle=dataBundle;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_details_customer, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_logout:
            login_pref = getSharedPreferences("Login Pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = login_pref.edit();
            editor.putString("username", null);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            /*editor.clear();*/
            editor.commit();
            finish();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
public Action getIndexApiAction() {
    Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
            .setName("Details_customer Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
            .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
            .build();
    return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
            .setObject(object)
            .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
    client.disconnect();
}

//deleted

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Cust_Details_basic cust_basic = new Cust_Details_basic();
                cust_basic.setArguments(dataBundle);
                return cust_basic;
            case 1:
                Cust_Details_address address = new Cust_Details_address();
                address.setArguments(dataBundle);
                return address;
           /* case 2:
                Cust_Details_last details_last = new Cust_Details_last();
                return details_last;*/
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    /***
     * new addition
     ***/
    public void showFragment(String val) {
        System.out.println(val);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Basic Info";
            case 1:
                return "Address";
           /* case 2:
                return "Address";*/
        }
        return null;
    }
}}
```

Cust_Details_basic.java Here is my Edittext i want to send the value to next fragment

```
public class Cust_Details_basic extends Fragment {

EditText finame;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;//For Loading activity..

public interface FragmentDataListener{

    void onFragmentDataUpdated(Bundle dataBundle);

}
private FragmentDataListener mFragmentDataListener;
@Override

public void onAttach( Context context )
{
    super.onAttach( context );
    mFragmentDataListener=(FragmentDataListener)getActivity();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_customer_1, container, false);
    finame = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.fname);
   /**********************************************/
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("fname",finame.getText().toString());
    mFragmentDataListener.onFragmentDataUpdated(bundle);
     /*********************************************/
    return view;
}}
```

Here is Cust_Details_address.java here i want Edittext value

```
public class Cust_Details_address extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

Button btnsubmit;
String fname,firstname;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_customer_2, container, false);


    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

            if (bundle != null) {
                firstname = bundle.getString("fname",fname);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"fname:"+firstname,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("First Name:","=======>"+firstname);

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Am Empty:",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


    btnsubmit = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);
    btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}}
```

Comment: Need more code to analyze the situation, are you using `Viewpager`? `FragmentManager`? Which mechanism loads fragments? . Note that his may be mark as duplicate relating to topics like [passing data between fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments).

Comment: am using Viewpager

Comment: I misunderstood at first, see what you need to to is pass bundle back to activity, then when Viewpager loads new fragment, it will attach that bundle calling setArguments(), you can implement an interface will show you code soon.

Comment: plz show in code. Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cust_Details_address.java I Override the method like this

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        String firstname = ((EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fname)).getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Hi "+firstname ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }    });
```

I got the result which i have accepted. Thank you so much 'Talha' for your needful help.

Answer (score 1):

In your activity define interface, bundle object, then call interface method of Activity instance with data from your fragment:

In **Details_customer** activity you do this,

```
  public class Details_customer extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements Cust_Details_basic.FragmentDataListener {

        SharedPreferences login_pref,IP;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;//For Loading activity..
        Bundle dataBundle;

        ..... other code

    // override method of interface

    @override void onFragmentDataUpdated(Bundle dataBundle)
    {

       this.dataBundle=dataBundle;
    }
    ...... other code
    // in SectionsPagerAdapter adapter
          @Override public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Cust_Details_basic cust_basic = new Cust_Details_basic();
                    cust_basic.setArguments(dataBundle); // remember to update
                                                        //bundle object as per requirement
                    return cust_basic;
                case 1:
                    Cust_Details_address address = new Cust_Details_address();
                    address.setArguments(dataBundle);
                    return address;


     /* case 2:
                        Cust_Details_last details_last = new Cust_Details_last();

                        return details_last;*/
                }
                return null;
            }
```

In your **Cus_Details_basic** Fragment, declare interface:

```
public class Cust_Details_basic extends Fragment {

    public interface FragmentDataListener{

    void onFragmentDataUpdated(Bundle dataBundle);

    }

private FragmentDataListener mFragmentDataListener;


// create fragment object and initialize it in onAttach()

@Override public void onAttach( Context context )
    {
        super.onAttach( context );


        mFragmentDataListener=(FragmentDataListener)getActivity();


    }

// then update your onCreate as:

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_customer_1, container, false);
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("fname",fname);
    //fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    mFragmentDataListener.onFragmentDataUpdated(bundle);
    // this will update dataBundle object in your activity
return view;
}
```

This will call `onFragmentDataUpdated()` of your `Details_customer` class, which will update its `dataBundle` object, now whenever `Viewpager` changes, you should be able to `setArguments()` with this `Bundle` object, and eventually `getArguments()` in `onCreate` of that fragment will be able to retrieve data.

***Useful links:***

[Communicating between Fragments.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

[How To Communicate Between Fragments and Activities in Android.](http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131672/discussion-on-answer-by-talha-send-data-from-fragment-to-fragment-using-tab-layo).

Answer (score 1):

**CallBacks(interface)** and **Bundles** are recommended way but this is a quick solution:

**YourActivity:**

```
 public void randomMethod(String val){
 System.out.println(val);
}
```

**Fragment1:**

```
onClick(){
 ((YourActivity) getActivity()).randomMethod(yourString1);
 }
```

**Fragment2:**

```
onClick(){
 ((YourActivity) getActivity()).randomMethod(yourString2);
 }
```

You can call that method from any fragment of an activity and use the updated value.

Comment: i didn't get you what you told.

Comment: write randomMethod in your activity and then update the value of that method from fragments and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Since all the fragment are in view pager that means they share the same activity.So just put the value inside the intent and get it in any fragment of that view pager, no need to pass the data separately in bundle.

In your `Cust_Details_basic` Fragment (Save it like this)

```
getActivity().getIntent().putExtra("name",fname);
```

In `Cust_Details_address` Fragment (Get it like this )

```
String fname = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```

Comment: How to send text box input value..?

Comment: `String fname = editText.getText().toString();`
`getActivity().getIntent().putExtra("name",fname);`

Comment: finame = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.fname);

Comment: finame = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.fname);                                    String fir_name = finame.getText().toString(); getActivity().getIntent().putExtra("name",fir_name); //sending null

Comment: make sure it has some text in it

Comment: Yes am giving value

Comment: is it still giving null ?

Comment: Yes its giving null