# How to send data between fragments in different activities

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I've been working in infoSec for almost a decade and now I'm trying to pivot into Android development. I'm completely new in the field of Android. This question has probably been answered before, but I didn't find anyone using pictures. So here we go:

I want to grasp this thing with Fragments and activities.
[Activities and fragments image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbYL4.png)

Basically I want to do a simple thing; get the result from GameFragment, pass it to GameActivity, pass it to ResultActivity, and then show it in the result fragment. (Or if there is another way to communicate with fragments in different activities)

Comment: you need to pass data from fragment to activity, then from activity to another activity, then - from another activity to a fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is many way below i mention :

1. you can use [shared preferences.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)
2. you can use [sqlite.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)
3. you can pass data using [intent.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16036693/8164071)

Links will provide brief knowledge about this topics.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parent `Activity` of a `Fragment` by using `getActivity()` method. To pass data between activities you can use `Intent` s.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be use of static variable in any common Class or in secondActivity.
If you use in second receive that value using

```
variable = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getInt("key");
```

Then use "variable" value.
Or declare in a common Class as like

```
public static int variable;
```

Assign value

```
CommonClassName.variable = 1;
```

Then use it.