# How to pass data from fragment to another fragment in android using java?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, fragment

Now I got all data from API and I displayed it in Homefragment now I want the title to the next fragment which is called overviewfragment. Actually overviewfragment is in emptyactivity so now how to pass data from one fragment to another fragment.

```
class MostCrowdedRecyclerAdapter {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TopViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_layout_layout_5, parent, false);
        return new TopViewHolder(view);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TopViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.restaurantName.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.distance.setText(list.get(position).getDistance() + " Mile");
        vybeAPI = Float.valueOf(list.get(position).getVybe());
        holder.vybe.setText(vybeAPI + "%");
        //   setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);
        holder.v.setOnClickListener(v -> {                                        <--here I did Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), EmptyActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Restaurant", getItemId(position));
            context.startActivity(i);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int limit = 6;
        return Math.min(list.size(), limit);
    }


    OverViewFragment:
    String data;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_over_view, container, false);
        TextView singletitle = view.findViewById(R.id.single);
        try {
            data = String.valueOf(Intent.getIntent("Restaurant").getExtras());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here I need to pass title from homefragment to overviewfragment but overviewfragment is in emptyactivity.

Comment: if your fragments are in two different activities, you can look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44584741/908821

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass values between Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

Need to two steps:

1. Send data from Homefragment to EmptyActivity.

   for this, you could use `putExtra()` method.
2. Set data from EmptyActivity to OverviewFragment.

   for this, you could use `setArgument()` method.