# getArguments() returns null (Value from Adapter passed to Fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know there are duplicate questions for this. But their problem is between `Activity` and `Fragment` . My problem is about passing a value from `Adapter` to `Fragment`.

I Toast the value from adapter and it shows the correct value. I used the `putString` and `setArguments` methods but it returns null.

Here is what I did in my Adapter:

```
 Bundle cart_bundle = new Bundle();
        cart_bundle.putString("total", String.valueOf(total_amount));
        Cart_Fragment fragment = new Cart_Fragment();
        fragment.setArguments(cart_bundle);
        ((User_Activity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .commit();
```

Here is how I receive the argument in Fragment :

```
Bundle cart_bundle = this.getArguments();
tv_total_amount.setText("Total Amount: "+ cart_bundle.getString("total"));
```

Maybe there is something wrong in `((User_Activity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .commit();`

There is an error if I try to replace the User_Activity to Fragment.

**P.S.**
I don't need to use `replace()` method because the adapter is an adapter for the list view in the fragment.

Comment: share logcat error...

Comment: you create the new fragment, and don't use it. Why you do that?

Comment: If you don't replace the current fragment, how will you use the new instance of `Cart_Fragment` that you created with the new arguments?

Comment: @KamranAhmed can you tell me what should be my parameters inside the replace method?  I tried adding replace(R.id.user_cart_fragment_container, fragment) but it made my fragment blank.

Comment: pl share you complete adapter code.

Comment: Nothing helped?

Comment: @KamranAhmed I entirely changed my method. I didn't solve for the total in the fragment and solved it in the adapter. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The best and good way to pass the adapter is first you have pass the object of the class from where you create the adapter . suppose :-

Adapter adapter=new Adapter(activityname or fragmentname.class);

here on click of item In adapter class;-

```
adapter.updateData(xyz,abz)
```

will create the method in that Fragment.

IN Fragment , you have to make interface that will update the data or you can directly call fragment , here you get the how to pass data
[How to pass values between Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments)

or you can

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("total", String.valueOf(total_amount));
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are getting the argument is wrong. Fragment has setArgument method which you need to override in your code and one your load your fragment you can call fragment instance and setargument.

So your fragment class will look like

```
public class Cart_Fragment extends Fragment{
    public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
         super.setArguments(args);
         //Get the argument here.
    }
}
```

Modify your adapter code as

```
Cart_Fragment fragment = new Cart_Fragment();
((User_Activity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit();

Bundle cart_bundle = new Bundle();
cart_bundle.putString("total", String.valueOf(total_amount));
fragment.setArguments(cart_bundle);
```

Comment: I will be receiving the value in Cart_Fragment. isn't it supposed to be getArguments instead of setArguments in public void setArguments()? sorry I'm confused.

Comment: oh i see. so it's an override. sorry will try this one.

Comment: it returns an error sir. "null object reference" when i tried to do total = Double.parseDouble(args.getString("total")); inside the setArguments() method.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of `Cart_Fragment`, setting the new arguments to it but never using it. The instance being used (the one that was actually transacted to `replace` or `add`) and this new instance of the `Fragment` are not the same. Hence, you will not get the arguments in the existing `Fragment` magically.

What you can do instead is keep a reference of the Fragment you first transacted and pass the values to it using a custom method of your own like:

```
public class Cart_Fragment extends Fragment {
    public void setNewTotal(String total) {
         tv_total_amount.setText("Total Amount: " + total);
    }
}
```

And in your adapter:

```
fragment.setNewTotal(String.valueOf(total_amount));
```

---

If you have used the `Fragment` right in the XML like:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/cart_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.Cart_Fragment"
    ...
```

you can get the instance of the fragment with:

```
Cart_Fragment fragment = ((Cart_Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.cart_fragment));
```

Comment: sorry sir but the logcat says "Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference" in the TextView

Comment: Did you do it on the fragment being used? Or did you create a new instance of it?

Comment: Cart_Fragment fragment = new Cart_Fragment();

        fragment.setNewTotal(String.valueOf(total_amount));

Comment: that's what I did sir. am I missing something? or is it wrong?

Comment: Yes. You are not supposed to do `new Cart_Fragment()` again, call that method on the instance that is already transacted.

Comment: How do you transact the fragment for the first time? Are you transacting it with Java code or have you declared it in the XML with `<fragment>` tag?