# Not able to pass string value from one fragment to another

Tags: java, android, string, android-fragments

I know there are so many qustions regarding this , but none of them are solving my problem 
I want to pass a string variable from one fragment to other, here is the code I did. but I am getting error (I will show the error)

from first fragment I did

```
Desc_1 ldf = new Desc_1 ();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("YourKey", "YourValue");
ldf.setArguments(args);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame, ldf).commit();
```

and incoming second fragment I did like

```
public class Desc_1 extends Fragment {

    public Desc_1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_desc_1,container,false);

        String value = getArguments().getString("YourKey");

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), value,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return rootview;

    }
}
```

I am getting error like

```
07-27 20:31:06.386 26816-26816/com.example.jaison.newsclient E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.jaison.newsclient, PID: 26816
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
       at layout.Desc_1.onCreateView(Desc_1.java:34)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2239)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1332)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2063)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:725)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:861)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
if(bundle != null)
    String value = bundle.getString("YourKey");
```

Comment: can u explain why it is happening ?

Comment: get the `Bundle` you sent and test id it's empty if not get the data

Answer (score 1):

Just check if `getArguments()` is not null inside your fragment, and then inside the curly braces add your code

**Example:**

```
Bundle bundle_arguments = getArguments();
if(bundle_arguments != null) {
    // your code 
}
```

Comment: can u post the answer

Comment: you gotta know how to make something based on what someone told you. giving you a complete solution doesn't help you in the long term :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer for passing values between fragments

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626004/5065318

Comment: You should flag the question as a duplicate if you think the question has been asked and answered before.