# Add nested fragments in Parent fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components

I have an SchoolActivity that has two buttons:
-Primary (adds the PrimaryFragment)
-Secondary (adds the SecondaryFragment)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.yuv.mycollege.MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_primary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Primary"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_secondary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Secondary"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Main content area for fragments-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="4dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Both the fragments has content and footer area, which are themselves are fragments (PrimaryContentFragment, PrimaryFooterFragment, SecondaryContentFragment, SecondaryFooterFragment)

I am adding the fragments from the activity using:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Button button = (Button)view;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Going to Add Children", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_primary:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main_container, new PrimaryFragment())
                    .addToBackStack("primary")
                    .commit();
            break;
        case R.id.button_secondary:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main_container, new SecondaryFragment())
                    .addToBackStack("secondary")
                    .commit();
            break;
    }
}
```

And, finally adding the each children fragments using:
The layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        ></FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_container"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        ></FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The children fragments adding:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.primary_fragment, container, false);
        getChildFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.content_container, new PrimaryContentFragment())
                .add(R.id.footer_container, new PrimaryFooterFragment())
                .addToBackStack("primarychildren")
                .commit();

        return view;
    }
```

I am adding the similar logics for the another fragment also and so on for the rest which is working.

**THE PROBLEM:**
The solution as stated is working but seems as very raw naive approach. Could anybody suggest the better architecture I could follow such as:

- all the fragments (Primary/Secondary/...) uses the same designs so
  can I create some base class to inherit common features
- all the footer are similar for all of fragments but with simple text change
  (might be like breadcrumb) So, Can I use same footer for all
  fragments with some settext method ...
- how can I effectively communicate between activity and fragments

BEING A NEW ANDROID DEV, MY ONLY CONCERN IS AM I DOING THE RIGHT WAY !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `bundle` :-

```
  ContentFragment content=new ContentFragment();
  content.setArguments( ( new Bundle()).putString("value","primary"));

getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.content_container, content)
            .add(R.id.footer_container, new PrimaryFooterFragment())
            .addToBackStack("primarychildren")
            .commit();
```

Similarly For secondary use :-

```
  ContentFragment content=new ContentFragment();
  content.setArguments( ( new Bundle()).putString("value","secondary"));
```

> Use same `content` and  `footer` fragments just set the texts by using `bundle arguments`

Answer (score 0):

> All the fragments (Primary/Secondary/...) uses the same designs so can
>   I create some base class to inherit common features

If they are using the same design and with slight changes in their content, then there's no need of create different `Fragment` classes. You can just pass necessary values from your calling `Activity` or `Fragment` to populate the contents in each of your child fragments.

> All the footer are similar for all of fragments but with simple text
>   change (might be like breadcrumb) So, Can I use same footer for all
>   fragments with some settext method ...

If they are just simple text changes, then please use the `setArguments` and `getArguments` methods to pass values between `Fragment`s rather creating different `Fragment` classes.

Here's how you can [pass values between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16036693/3145960). And here's how you [can pass data from your `Activity` to `Fragment`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12739968/3145960).

> How can I effectively communicate between activity and fragments

Please follow the two links above to communicate between `Activity` and `Fragment`.

**Update**

Following up the comment, as you have said that the `PrimaryFragment` and `SecondaryFragment` are mostly likely, I would suggest you to have one single `Fragment` having all these. Instead of having `PrimaryFragment`, `SecondaryFragment` and a `CommonFragment`, you might consider a single `Fragment` having the footer `Fragment` as well. When you are about to launch an instance of that `Fragment`, just pass necessary values to populate data as the contents of those `Fragment`.

Please let me know if I have not clarified enough.

Comment: @Murshed I was thinking if I could use some CommonFragment with contentFragment and FooterFragment classes inside them and inherit PrimaryFragment and SecondaryFragment from them so I don't even need to include footer and some property in CommonFragment will be used to change values for footer. (might be design flaw). Can we address that way?

Comment: I tried to solve the problem such as: (1) mainactivity to instantiate commonfragment and add to its container
(2) commonfragment responsibility do decide which fragment to draw in its container
(3) Each individualfragment (eg PrimaryFragment) will add both contentfragment (unique) and footerfragment as single transaction
into its view
(4) footerfragment is the commonfooterfragment which will accept the arguments to show the fragment specific breadcrumb.
[Sorry if you didn't get it ... the work i tried to do is at https://github.com/gitaarush/SOAndroidApp/tree/feature_design)