# Getting Null Value in Arraylist while sending value from one Fragment to another fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

### SecondFragment

> I have create a Tab Activity. I am getting null value in ArrayList while sending value from one Fragment to other Fragment. I am getting the value in second fragment but unable to setting it up  ArrayList. i am using `RecyclerView` for showing the values in row.

```
    import android.app.Application;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.lang.reflect.Array;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.jar.Attributes;

    public class Registration_Details extends Fragment {

        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        ArrayList list;
        List<String> list2;
        MyAddapter myAddapter;
        Context context;
        Bundle bundle;
        TextView textView,textView2,textView3;
        String name, contact,email;
        private Random mRandom = new Random();
        private TextView memail,mphone,muser;
        View rootView;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ArrayValueAdd();


        }

        private void ArrayValueAdd() {

            Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

            if (bundle != null) {

                name = bundle.getString("Name");
                contact = bundle.getString("Contact");
                email = bundle.getString("Email");




            }


            list = new ArrayList<String>(3);


            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {


//Here unable to getting the value
                list.add(name);
                list.add(contact);
                list.add(email);

//Getting the value in Log.e

                Log.e(name, "This is my message");


            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            ArrayValueAdd();
        }

            @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.registration_details, container, false);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
            linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);






                RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv);




            myAddapter = new MyAddapter(getActivity(), list, new OnMyItemClickListner() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClicked(int pos) {


                }
            }, new OndeleteItem() {

                @Override
                public void ondelete(int pos) {



                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(name), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    myAddapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

        }




            );

             recyclerView.setAdapter(myAddapter);
            return rootView;
        }


    }
```

### FirstFragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.service.carrier.CarrierMessagingService;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Registration_Tab  extends Fragment {

    EditText editTextName, editTextContact,editTextEmail;
    View rootView;
    Button submitButton;
    String name,contact,email;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.registration_tab, container, false);

        editTextName = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

        editTextContact = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextContact);

        editTextEmail = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);

        submitButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);




        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                name = editTextName.getText().toString();
                contact = editTextContact.getText().toString();
                email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();

                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Name",name);
                bundle.putString("Contact",contact);
                bundle.putString("Email",email);






            FragmentTransaction transection=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Registration_Details registration_details=new Registration_Details();
                registration_details.setArguments(bundle); //data being send to SecondFragment
                transection.replace(R.id.constraintLayout, registration_details);
                transection.commit();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Goingg  " +name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });






        return rootView;
    }


}
```

### Updated SecondFragment

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;

public class Registration_Details extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList list;
    List<String> list2;
    MyAddapter myAddapter;
    Context context;
    Bundle bundle;
    TextView textView,textView2,textView3;
    String name, contact,email;
    private Random mRandom = new Random();
    private TextView memail,mphone,muser;
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.registration_details, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


            Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

            if (bundle != null) {

                name = bundle.getString("Name");
                contact = bundle.getString("Contact");
                email = bundle.getString("Email");




            }


            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add(name);
            list.add(contact);
            list.add(email);

            Log.e(name, "This is my message");




        myAddapter = new MyAddapter(getActivity(), list, new OnMyItemClickListner() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int pos) {


            }
        }, new OndeleteItem() {

            @Override
            public void ondelete(int pos) {



                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(name), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                myAddapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

    }




        );

         recyclerView.setAdapter(myAddapter);
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

### MyAddapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.suyash.shivrai_tech.OnMyItemClickListner;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAddapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAddapter.MyViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    List<String> list,list2;
String s1,s2,s3;
    public OnMyItemClickListner onitem;
    public OndeleteItem ondeleteitem;


    public MyAddapter(Context context, List<String> list, OnMyItemClickListner onitem, OndeleteItem ondeleteItem){

        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.onitem = onitem;
        this.ondeleteitem = ondeleteItem;


    }

    public MyAddapter(FragmentActivity activity, List<String> list, OndeleteItem ondeleteItem) {
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, viewGroup, false);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {



        myViewHolder.textView.setText(list.get(i));

        myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

             onitem.onItemClicked(i);


            }
        });

        myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ondeleteitem.ondelete(i);
            }
        });





    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount( ) {

        return list.size();

    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textView,textView2;

       public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
           super(itemView);

           textView =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv);




       }
   }

}
```

Comment: why does your first and second fragment look the same?

Comment: @ MadScientist Sorry that was my mistake.

Comment: can you provide your log?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your list initialisation and method placement,

Do this:

`list = new ArrayList<String>();`

and call the`ArrayValueAdd` method only in the `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated` of your fragment, right now the methods are executed with the lifecycle of the `Activity` rather than of the `Fragment` which makes them never execute as the `Activity` has already passed the states.

Also there's not need to loop, you can just do:

```
list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(name);
list.add(contact);
list.add(email);
```

no loops nothing.

Fragments cannot pass data directly to another fragment in order to do so you need it to flow from the parent `Activity`

Check this answer for a detailed explanation: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626004/4820556)

Comment: Still not getting the value inside "list.add(name)" but its printing the value in Log.e(name +"This is My Message")

Comment: did you change the method placement and the initialisation as well?

Comment: also why are you looping? why is the for loop present

Comment: @ MadScientist can you please tell me how to do that correction in code. i am new in android.Loop is only for increasing the value.

Comment: Still not getting the value inside the (liast.add("name") showing the null value

Comment: Yes I have paste the updated code please check once.

Comment: the updated code looks fine, can your adapter code as well, and are you getting the logs?

Comment: yes my adapter code is same as it is. and its printing me the log.e but not in array list.

Comment: there is no code for the adapter, there was in the initial edit, but it seems you removed it.

Comment: Ohh Sorry for that. I again updated the MyAddapter Code

Comment: Well, this should work beautifully, can you post a log at two places, can you add a log inside the `onBindViewHolder` and print the value and one just before you call `setAdapter` on the RV to print the size of the list. can you get back to me with the results.

Comment: I am getting log inside the onBindViewHolder and log before recyclerView.setAdapter(myAddapter); but with null value

Comment: you're getting null in both?

Comment: yes i am getting null just before  recyclerView.setAdapter(myAddapter). and same as in OnBindHolder

Comment: like you're getting null for the size? that can't be possible. maybe you're printing the value. that means bundle is null, which means arguments are not coming, and you're using FragmentManager for a v4.Fragment, try replacing `getFragmentManager` with `getSupportFragmentManager` and here's what you're doing wrong, fragments cannot pass data to another fragments directly check the edit im making