# Share EditText value between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have 2 fragments, `FragmentB` & `FragmentC` which are inherit from `FragmentA`.
and `MainActivity` with `supportFragmentManager` to switch between fragments.
In `FragmentB` & `FragmentC` the user can insert his name to `EditText`.
each fragment has it's own `EditText` on it's layout.
but when I switch between the fragments I want the current value will be equal on both fragments.
so if the user input on `FragmentB` the name "ab" and switch to `FragmentC`
he will see "ab" on the `EditText` and can append "c" so when he will switch back to `FragmentB` he will see "abc" on the `EditText`.
I've mentioned that both of the fragments are inherit from `FragmentA` and I thought to do this by declaring protected `EditText` on `FragmentA` so both `FragmentB` and `FragmentC` will initialize the `EditText`.
and to add `TextWatcher` to this `EditText` but the text is not updated properly while switching the fragments.
any other ideas, how can I really create shared `EditText` so both of the fragments will change and read it's value on realtime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass values between Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments)

Comment: @ADM thanks! it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity, add these:

```
private String userName;

private String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

private void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
```

You may also want to save/restore `userName` via `onSaveInstanceState()` etc, but for now we can skip worrying about that.

In both of your fragments, add this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MyActivity activity = (MyActivity) getActivity(); // replace with your activity class name
    nameEditText.setText(activity.getUserName()); // replace with your EditText
}
```

And in your `TextWatcher`, set the value back to the activity:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    MyActivity activity = (MyActivity) getActivity(); // replace with your activity class name
    activity.setUserName(s.toString());
}
```

Comment: thanks! this is exactly what I did! thanks to you and @ADM suggested post