# pass data class between two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I think I'm doing it wrong but this is my situation.
I'm getting json data inside a fragment then process it with Gson to a data class and display it. What I need is to use this data again inside another fragment in a custom spinner adapter which is ready.

As much as I understand it's impossible to pass objects so how can I do this !?
I have tried to use bundle and it didn't work

the onResponse method (First fragment)

```
            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
            val jsonString = response?.body()?.string()
            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            val data = gson.fromJson(jsonString,currancyModel::class.java)
            countryData = data
            activity?.runOnUiThread {
                rootView.recyclerView.adapter = CountryAdapter(data)
                }
        }
```

the data class

```
data class currancyModel(val items: List<Item>)
data class Item(val countray :String,val rate:String)
```

the getView in the custom spinner adapter inside the second fragment 
(I need my data here)

```
    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
    val view    = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custome_spinner,null)
    val img = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.spinner_image) as ImageView
    val countary_name     = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.spinner_country) as TextView
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.us)
    countary_name.setText(country!![p0].countray)
    return view
}
```

Comment: Its not  impossible to pass objects via `Bundle` .You can use `Parcelable` in this case . Follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments.

Comment: you can use interface or check with ViewModel to communicate between fragments https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing or you can check for passing bundle as argument as per your requirement

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do you display two fragments in your `Activity` simultaneously? If so, you can pass the data through it. Or implement some interface/observable/livedata to pass the data between the fragments.
2. If `Fragment A` fetches the data and then you change `Fragment A` to `Fragment B`, make your data classes `Parcelable` and then pass it as arguments when creating `Fragment B`:

```
companion object {
    fun newInstance(yourData : DataClass) = FragmentB().apply { arguments = Bundle().apply {  putParcelable("dataKey",yourData) }
}
```

Note: you can annotate your data class with `@Parcelize`. Compiler will then generate all `Parcelable` methods and factory class for you.

After you passed the data to `Fragment B` on creation, retrieve it with, for example:

`val data: YourData by lazy { arguments?.getParcelable("dataKey") as YourData }`

Comment: the two fragments isn't in the same display so its the second scenario thanks alots , one more question ! as you can see I have two data class one contain a list of the other , which one should I implement the Parcelable in ?

Comment: You should consider passing just `items: List<Item>` from `data class currancyModel`. Since `List` collection is not parcelable by itself, you need to pass it as a typed array. Use `putParcelableArray(key, list.toTypedArray)`, then retrieve it with `arguments?.getParcelableArray()`.

Comment: something isn't right , I have did everything as you said but I always  get null on **data**  variable  , according to your example  the data should be passed from Fragment A like this ` FirstFragment.newInstance(data) `  inside the above onResponse method ?! Right ?

Comment: Have you changed `data` type to `Array<Item>`?

Comment: yes I did , I just figure out that the problem that **Fragment B** runs before **Fragments A**  therefore when try to get the value with parcelabl in **Fragments B** its get null because **Fragments A** didn't put the value yet

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it is possible to pass objects from one fragment to another given your object class should implement Parcelable. And passing the object through the bundle by calling putParcelable on the bundle object.

```
1. class CurrancyModel : Parcelable {
  //Implement Parcelable 
}
```

And pass it between the fragments via Bundle.

```
2.var fragment = YourFragment().apply {
   arguments = Bundle().apply{ putParcelable("dataKey",yourData) }
}
```

Comment: This work to me after implement my data class with parcelable, them I am able to pass parcelable data between fragments using putParcelable(), thanks

Answer (score -1):

An idea could be to use a singleton data class, with a `HashMap<String, Object>` having a key with some kind of ID you create yourself, and then the value being the object you want to be able to retrieve. So in the `onResponse` you will add your data to the `HashMap` in the dataclass and then just retrieve it from the other class.