# How to pass my one fragment data to another fragment in the same activity?

Tags: java, android

I want to send my location information in MapFragment to MyDialog fragment. Because I want to store in database on MyDialog.

I tried bundle but I cant do it.

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private static final String TAG = "MapFragment";

public Double lat, lon;
GoogleMap map;
boolean isAdded = true, click;
FloatingActionButton but;
Dialog dialog;

public MapFragment() {
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    but = view.findViewById(R.id.showDialog);
    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isAdded) {
                click = true;
                isAdded = false;
            } else {
                showDialog();
                isAdded = true;
            }
        }

        private void showDialog() {
            MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
            dialog.setTargetFragment(MapFragment.this, 1);
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialog");
        }
    });

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            if (click == true) {
                lat = latLng.latitude;
                lon = latLng.longitude;

                // new LatLng(lat, lon)
                Log.i("on clicked location", "loc: " + new LatLng(lat, lon));
                LatLng loc = new LatLng(lat, lon);

               // Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon)).title("location"));
                sendLocation(googleMap);
                but.setImageDrawable(ActivityCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_check));

                //sending location mydialog fragment
                MyDialog fragment = new MyDialog();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putDouble("Lat", lat);
                b.putDouble("Lon", lon);
                fragment.setArguments(b);

            }
        }
    });
}



public void sendLocation(final GoogleMap googleMap){
    map = googleMap;
    LatLng location= new LatLng(lat, lon);
    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon)).title("location"));

}
}
```

MyDialog fragment:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment
    implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
private static final String TAG = "MyDialog";

private Spinner spinner;

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}


public interface OnInputSelected {
    void sendInput(String input);
}

public OnInputSelected mOnInputSelected;

//widgets
private EditText mInput;
private Button mSave, mCancel;
private EditText nameSurname, address;
private Location location;


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_map, container, false);

    spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.addType);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.addType));
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(aa);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    mSave = view.findViewById(R.id.save_action);
    mCancel = view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_action);
    nameSurname = view.findViewById(R.id.nameSurname);
    address = view.findViewById(R.id.address);

    mCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: closing dialog");
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });


    mSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: capturing input.");
            String nameSurname_ = nameSurname.getText().toString();
            String address_ = address.getText().toString();
            String addType_ = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();

            Dialog dialog = new Dialog();

            String input = nameSurname_ + " " + address_ + " " + addType_;


            if (!input.equals("")) {

                dialog.setName_surname(nameSurname_);
                dialog.setAddress(address_);
                dialog.setAddress_type(addType_);
             //   dialog.setLocation(location);


                MyDB.getInstance(getContext()).myDAO().addDialog(dialog);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Dialog created. with " + nameSurname_ + " " + address_ + " " + addType_ , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            nameSurname.setText("");
            address.setText("");

            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        mOnInputSelected = (OnInputSelected) getTargetFragment();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onAttach: ClassCastException : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass values between Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments)

Comment: If you are ok with using external libraries, I suggest the EventBus Library. It helps to communicate between activities, fragments with ease