# How to set spinner value in another frgament in Android

Tags: android, spinner

Hi in the below code passing string value to another fragment. In the second Fragment getting the value.
Now I want to set that value to my spinner.
can any one help me how to set the value to spinner.

OneFragement.java:

```
Fragment fragment = new SecondFragement();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putString("task_types", task_types);//training
fragment.setArguments(args);
        loadFragment(fragment);
```

SecondFragement.java:

```
    String task_types = getArguments().getString("task_types");//training
    spinnertaskType=rootView.findViewById(R.id.task_type);

 task_typelist.clear();
            String task_types = getArguments().getString("task_types");
            task_typelist.add(task_types);
              ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, task_typelist);
             dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnertaskType.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
```

Comment: You want to send arraylist from one fragment to another one or you want to send just one string?

Comment: @MMG String only how to pass

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments

Comment: passing is not an issue i am done with that part.How to set that string value to spinner

Comment: OK, add it to your arraylist and give arraylist to spinner.

Comment: Already i have some arraylist already in second fragemnt .If I am Adding new arraylist and adding to spinner.same list with new string was added to spinner

Comment: OK, what is the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214160/discussion-between-jyo-srijyo-and-mmg).

Answer (score 0):

In this code you will have just one item in your string, you should add `task_types` to your **arraylist**. You shouldn't clear your **arraylist** before that.