# Android: Kotlin pass Data from Dialog to BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am trying to pass data from dialog to bottom sheet fragment. Here is how my bottom sheet fragment opens my dialog fragment

```
     editAddDate.setOnClickListener{
             val timeDatePickerDialog = TimeDatePickerDialog(requireContext())
             timeDatePickerDialog.setOnDismissListener(this)
             timeDatePickerDialog.show()



         }
```

in my dialog fragment I implemented  Dialog(context),TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener,
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener as the following :

```
class TimeDatePickerDialog(context: Context) : Dialog(context),TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener,
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private lateinit var pickDate: TextView
    private lateinit var pickTime: TextView
    private lateinit var repeat: TextView
    private lateinit var done: TextView
    private lateinit var cancel: TextView
    private lateinit var selectedDate: String
    private lateinit var selectedTime: String
    private lateinit var binding: TimeDatePickerDialogBinding


    var day=0
    var month=0
    var year=0
    var time=0
    var minutes=0

    var savedDay=""
    var savedMonth=""
    var savedYear=""
    var savedTime=0
    var savedMinutes=0



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(context),
            R.layout.time_date_picker_dialog,
            null,
            false
        )

        setContentView(binding.getRoot())



        pickDate=binding.setDate
        pickTime=binding.setTime
        repeat=binding.repeat
        cancel=binding.cancel
        done=binding.done

        initView()


    }


    override fun onTimeSet(view: TimePicker?, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int) {
        savedTime=hourOfDay
        savedMinutes=minute
        var time="$savedTime:$savedMinutes"
        selectedTime=time
        pickTime.text=selectedTime
    }

    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
        savedDay=dayOfMonth.toString()
        var currentMonth=month+1
        savedMonth=currentMonth.toString()
        savedYear=year.toString()
        var date="$savedDay,$savedMonth $savedYear"
        selectedDate=date

        pickDate.text = selectedDate

    }

    private fun getDateTimeCalendar(){
        val c=Calendar.getInstance()
        day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        time=c.get(Calendar.HOUR)
        minutes=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

    }

    private fun initView() {

        pickDate.setOnClickListener {
            getDateTimeCalendar()
            DatePickerDialog(context, R.style.PickerDialogTheme, this, year, month, day).show()

        }

        pickTime.setOnClickListener {
            getDateTimeCalendar()
            TimePickerDialog(context, R.style.PickerDialogTheme, this, time, minutes, true).show()
        }

        cancel.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
        }


       done.setOnClickListener {

            dismiss()}


    }


}
```

I want to send my date and time when done is clicked from this dialog to the bottom sheet dialog I cant find a way to do this I tried shared viewModels but I run into more issues than I expected can I do this in a simple way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass values between Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments)

Comment: is TimeDatePickerDialog your class?

Comment: @JavadDehban no because I am using host activity and multiple fragment I was able to pass data in the other fragments I used in my app by navigation component but I don't know why in dialog and bottom sheet I can't do that

Comment: @MingkangPan  TimeDatePickerDialog  is my class and it is declared as the following. class TimeDatePickerDialog(context: Context) : Dialog(context),TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener,
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

Comment: Why you don't send it as constructor parameter ?

Comment: @AliKhoshraftar How?

Comment: Your TimeDatePickerDialog needs context as first parameter. you can create another constructor that get two parameters. one is context (to initialize your main constructor) and two is what ever you want and store it in a variable in TimeDatePickerDialog class and use it whenever you want.

Comment: @AliKhoshraftar I got your point but how to pass this variable back to the parent fragment

Comment: @goodee if you need data back to parent fragment you have two choices : one is using broadcast and two is interface you pass as another parameter to TimeDatePickerDialog and implement it in parent fragment so you can always send data to parent fragment.

Comment: So the thing that's probably confusing everyone trying to answer is that `TimeDatePickerDialog` is not actually a `DialogFragment`... I fixed your question to remove references claiming that it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way by using sharedViewModel but you have to extends DialogFragment() instead of  Dialog(context) and the declare a variable to hold the sharedviewModel  value that you created in my case :
private val bottomSheetViewModel: BottomSheetViewModel by activityViewModels()

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is just to define an interface:

```
class TimeDatePickerDialog(context: Context) : Dialog(context) {

    interface OnDateSelectedListener {
        fun onDateSelected(date: Date)
    }

    private lateinit var selectedDate : Date
    var onDateSelectedListener : OnDateSelectedListener? = null

    fun initView() {
        doneButton.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
            onDateSelectedListener?.onDateSelected(selectedDate)
        }
    }
}
```

Set the listener from your BottomSheetDialog after you instantiated the DatePicker Dialog