# I want to make a comment page like Instagram but Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a comment page like Instagram. I want to make a fragment where users using the application can add comments. Comments are kept in firebase.
With the codes I wrote, the relevant section does not occur in firebase, and comments are not saved.

Yorumyaz2Fragment.java:

```
public class Yorumyaz2Fragment extends Fragment {
    EditText edit_yorumekle;
    TextView gonder1;
    ImageView image;

    String postid;
    String publisherid;
    FirebaseUser user;


    public Yorumyaz2Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_yorumyaz2, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Yorumlar");
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> getActivity().finish());
        edit_yorumekle=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_yorumekle);
        gonder1=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gonder1);
        image=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        Intent intent=getActivity().getIntent();
        postid=intent.getExtras().getString("postid");
        publisherid=intent.getExtras().getString("publisherid");


        gonder1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if(edit_yorumekle.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"boş yorum gönderemezsiniz",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else {
                yorumeklee();
            }
        });


        return  view;

    }

    private void yorumeklee() {
     if(postid !=null){

            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("yorumlar").child(postid);     
            HashMap<String,Object> hash=new HashMap<>();
            hash.put("yorum",edit_yorumekle.getText().toString());
            hash.put("gönderen",user.getUid());
            reference.push().setValue(hash);
            edit_yorumekle.setText("");
    }
}
```

fragment_yorumyaz2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Yorumyaz2Fragment">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/image">
        </com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:hint="Yorumunuzu giriniz"
            android:id="@+id/edit_yorumekle"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/gonder"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        </EditText>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gönder"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary"
            android:id="@+id/gonder1"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.geziproject.Yorumyaz2Fragment.onCreateView(Yorumyaz2Fragment.java:66)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2169)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1992)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem you're facing is that `postId` is null so when you call `.child(postId)` it's throwing an exception.

Now, `postId` is null because you aren't getting the extra value in the correct way.

Change this:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
postid=intent.getStringExtra("postid");
publisherid=intent.getStringExtra("publisherid");
```

To this:

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
postid = intent.getExtras().getString("postid");
publisherid = intent.getExtras().getString("publisherid");
```

And I'd suggest that you check `postId` is not null before you call `yorumeklee()` to avoid getting the exception you showed.

Comment: Please  @KübraOKUR if this answer solved your problem, consider marking it as the "accepted answer".

Comment: As you said, I tried to edit my code, but I got another error in logcat. Would you look again

Comment: I guess that you aren sending the data to the fragment in the wrong way, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16036693/7491884)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
postid=intent.getStringExtra("postid");
publisherid=intent.getStringExtra("publisherid");
```

part of the code. U create new Intent with `Intent intent=new Intent();` and then acces parameters of this intent. That's why you have value of `postid` null. You should pass the data to the fragment like this: [Send data from activity to fragment in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)