# how to send data between activity and its fragments?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, supportfragmentmanager

I am working on an app where click on an item in a recycler View opens another activity (Customer-Detail) where there are three Fragments in Tab layout .recycler view contains list of employees, I want to show the details of employee selected from list. I have stored All employee's data in SQLITE in "Employee" Table ( which contains Customer-Id ,Name ,Address ETC)  , Now I have Customer-ID (ID of selected Customer) in "Customer-Detail" Activity. I just want to send that "Customer-ID" value to three Fragments of this Customer-Detail Activity. It seems simple but I could not find any solution . Here is my CustomerDetail.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CustomerDetail">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/custID"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabInlineLabel="true"
            app:tabBackground="@color/lightRed"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is CustomerDetails.kt :

```
class CustomerDetail : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_detail)
        val extras: Bundle? = intent.extras
        val EmployeeID: Int = extras!!.getInt("id")
        
        sendToFragmentOrder(EmployeeID)
        
        val appbar = findViewById<AppBarLayout>(R.id.appbar)
        val tabLayout = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tablayout)
        val viewPager = findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.viewPager)
        setUpTabs()
    }

    private fun sendToFragmentOrder(id : Int) {
        // this method is not working...
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putInt("id",id)
        val fragmentOrder = OrderFragment()
        fragmentOrder.arguments = bundle
    }

    private fun setUpTabs() {
        val adapter = mPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        adapter.addFragment(OrderFragment(), "Orders")
        adapter.addFragment(ReceiptsFragment(), "Receipts")
        adapter.addFragment(ReportsFragment(), "Reports")
        val viewpager = findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.viewPager)
        viewpager.adapter = adapter
        val tab = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tablayout)
        tab.setupWithViewPager(viewpager)
    }
}
```

OrderFragment() Class :

```
class OrderFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val id = arguments?.getInt("id")

        val view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order, container, false)
        val tv = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.idtv)
        tv.text = id.toString()
        return  view }
}
```

i hope i explained my question well ...  i am new here so ... any help will be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass values between Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments)

Comment: yes i have... getArguments().getString("message") returns null

Answer (score 0):

use the same viewmodel:

in `Activity`:

```
val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
```

in `Fragment`:

```
val viewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

needs ktx artifcats, see https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel