# change text with Switch button in fragment

Tags: java, android

how to check switch position in to other fragment

First Fragment

```
          textView=view.findViewById(R.id.textview_first);

    // check  second fragment switch position and change text
```

Second Fragment

```
    aSwitch=view.findViewById(R.id.switch1);

    aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){

                //Checnge first fragment textview text to checked

            }else {
                //Checnge first fragment textview text to unchecked
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is this (Communication between Fragments):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63612656/7968986

With a String (checked/unchecked)

I assume you aren't using ViewModels/LiveData, otherwise you could also solve the problem with those

EDIT:

Just saw that you are using Java, you can find Java examples and the general android guide here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result

Answer (score 0):

To communicate between  two fragments in with java, most times we employ the concept of **interface**. where we you just use an interface then set the listeners on the fragments class then implement the action listeners on the main class controlling the fragments.

[Use this link to see how to set up an interface, attach listeners in the fragments and implement the interface on another class that will be used to pass the information between the two fragments](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/gestures-animations-flexible-uis/communicating-between-fragments-activities)

Comment: Yes. in the fragment that is listening the interface call. just get the string coming the prior fragment and to `.toUppercase()` to make it into upper case