# How to take a string then display it on a EditText

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a beginner in android studio (java) and I'm making a Hotel Reservation App. I have three types of rooms (Single, Deluxe, Suite). Each of the rooms has buttons that will redirect to a Reservation form https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXAWj.png. I want to take a string("Single", "Deluxe", "Suite"), depending on the button pressed then display it on the "Room Type" as seen on the image provided.

Comment: just put yourEditText.setText("Single"). (or "deluxe", "suite")

Comment: please show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

there are two straight forward ways to deal with your situation.

1. if you are opening the form in a new fragment/activity, you can just pass the data. For detail, you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16036693/9635486
2. or you can just change the `Room Type` editText to a [Spinner](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner) so that it can be handled within the same fragment

Answer (score 0):

First i dont know whick language you are working on it i answer it as a kotlin set for every button onclick listener like this

`(buttonSingle.setOnClickListener {},buttonDeluxe.setOnClickListener,  buttonSuite.setOnClickListener{})`

and then write inside of these blocks for example inside of button single button

```
val myString = single.text(in java getText).toString
```

and write it in your edittext with

```
edittextRoom.text(in java setText) = myString
```

this is all you need

Answer (score 0):

Create a dropdown list(for >3 options) or radio button(for ≤3 options) instead of getting input from user .it will more convenient way to show options