# Display the passing data between two fragments in recyclerView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have data taken from an API, I have added a button that when pressed will move (title, image, and some data from **FRAGMENT** to other **FRAGMENT**), this data is taken from **RECYCLERLVIEW** and will be shown in **RECYCLERVIEW**. But when the button is pressed, nothing happens and the data is not transmitted.

The project link if you want to take a deeper look "[Mox Project](https://github.com/MoatazBadawy/MOX)"

---

Here's the first adapter that I send data from

--- **CNNAdapter** ---

```
private List<Item> items = null;

@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
public void setCNNList(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new NewsViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_news,
                    parent,
                    false
            )
    );
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item News = items.get(position);
    ((NewsViewHolder) holder).setData(News);
    ((NewsViewHolder) holder).sendData(News);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (items == null) return 0;
    return items.size();
}

static class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final ImageView image;
    private final TextView title;
    private final TextView description;
    private final TextView source;
    private final TextView author;
    private final Button sendDataButton;
    private final Activity activity = new Activity();

    NewsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_news);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_news);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_news);
        source = itemView.findViewById(R.id.source_news);
        author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author_name_news);
        sendDataButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_save);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    void setData(Item news) {
        Glide.get(itemView.getContext()).clearMemory();
        // load images in MainThread
        activity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
            Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load((Objects.requireNonNull(news.getEnclosure())).getLink())
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                    .into(image);

            Glide.get(itemView.getContext()).clearMemory();
        });

        title.setText(news.getTitle());
        description.setText(Html.fromHtml(Objects.requireNonNull(news.getDescription()).replaceAll("(<(/)img>)|(<img.+?>)", ""), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
        source.setText(R.string.cnn);
        author.setText(R.string.author);
    }

    void sendData(Item news) {
        sendDataButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("title", news.getTitle());
            bundle.putString("image", Objects.requireNonNull(news.getEnclosure()).getLink());
            bundle.putString("source", "CNN");
            bundle.putString("author", "CNN editor's");
            bundle.putString("link", news.getLink());
            FavouriteFragment favouriteFragment = new FavouriteFragment();
            favouriteFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        });
    }
}
```

---

Here's the second adapter that I get the data and set it

--- **FavoriteAdapter** ---

```
public class FavoriteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();;
private Context context;

@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
public void setFavoriteList(ArrayList<Item> items, Context context) {
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new FavoriteViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_save,
                    parent,
                    false
            )
    );
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ((FavoriteViewHolder) holder).setData();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (items == null) return 0;
    return items.size();
}

static class FavoriteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final ImageView image;
    private final TextView title;
    private final TextView source;
    private final TextView author;
    private final Activity activity = new Activity();

    FavoriteViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_article_save);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_article_save);
        source = itemView.findViewById(R.id.source_article_save);
        author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author_name_article_save);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    void setData() {
        FavouriteFragment favouriteFragment = new FavouriteFragment();
        Bundle bundle = favouriteFragment.getArguments();
        String getTitle = bundle.getString("title");
        String getImage = bundle.getString("image");
        String getSource = bundle.getString("source");
        String getAuthor = bundle.getString("author");
        String getLink = bundle.getString("link");

        Glide.get(itemView.getContext()).clearMemory();
        // load images in MainThread
        activity.runOnUiThread (() -> {
            Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load((getImage))
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                    .into(image);

            Glide.get(itemView.getContext()).clearMemory();
        });

        title.setText(getTitle);
        source.setText(getSource);
        author.setText(getAuthor);
    }
}
```

---

---

My fragment that I display the data using recyclerview

--- **FavouriteFragment** ---

```
public class FavouriteFragment extends Fragment  {

private FragmentFavouriteBinding binding;
ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = FragmentFavouriteBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    requireActivity().setTitle("");
    initializeViews();
    return view;
}

private void initializeViews() {
    FavoriteAdapter adapter = new FavoriteAdapter();
    binding.recyclerViewFavorites.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext()));
    binding.recyclerViewFavorites.setHasFixedSize(true);
    binding.recyclerViewFavorites.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setFavoriteList(arrayList,getContext());
}
```

---

---

The project link if you want to take a deeper look "[Mox Project](https://github.com/MoatazBadawy/MOX)"

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Follow.........

Answer (score 0):

The displaying of Fragments is managed by **[FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager)**. You must pass an instance of FragmentManager to CNNAdapter as follows:

```
public class CNNAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CNNAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {

    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    public CNNAdapter(FragmentManager mFragmentManager) {
        this.mFragmentManager = mFragmentManager;
    }

    public void addData(List<> items) {
        list.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And then you display the fragment as follows:

```
FavouriteFragment favouriteFragment = new FavouriteFragment();
favouriteFragment.setArguments(bundle);
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,favouriteFragment).commit();
```

**R.id.fragment_container** is the view ID of the container in the layout xml of the activity that hosts the fragment. The container is usually a **FrameLayout**.

And then you instantiate CNNAdapter in the Fragment like this:

```
CNNAdapter cnnAdapter = new CNNAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. If you see my code you will find that I made all of that before. I tried your FragmentManger and It is not working.

Comment: Here's my project link, If you want to take a deeper look https://github.com/MoatazBadawy/MOX

Comment: There was a small bug in the code. I forgot to call the commit() method to commit  the fragment transaction. It should be like this `mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,favouriteFragment).commit();`

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems or issues that may cause the button not to show the passed data.
remember a view will only display when it gets data.
Here are some resources that might help:

- Passing Data between Fragments on Android Using ViewModel
  Managing UI-related data in activity lifecycles
  https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/passing-data-between-fragments-on-android-using-viewmodel-d47fa6773f9c
- [How to pass values between Fragments](http://%EF%BB%BFhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments)
- https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, I made most of these but also not working.

Comment: Here's my project link, If you want to take a deeper look https://github.com/MoatazBadawy/MOX

Comment: ok will see check it and update you