# take data from edit text in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have some edittext boxes (input type = phone) in a fragment. I need to get the value from them and store them in a variable called totalincome and pass this value to another fragment which has a textview. how to do this in the kotlin way. I'm a beginner.

is this the right way
`etincome.toString().toInt()`

Answer (score 0):

if input type you have phone , data type the variable must string

```
editText.text.toString()
```

Comment: Can you also suggest me how to do pass the value from the current fragment to another fragment?

Comment: check this[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16036693/16698614)

Answer (score 0):

in java and kotlin

```
editText.getText().toString()
```

kotlin

```
editText.text.toString()
```