# how to make getter setter method for string array

Tags: android, arrays, string, null

```
public class GlobalVariable extends Application {    
private static String[] array; 
    public static void setarray(String[] array) {
                GlobalVariable.array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
            }
         public static String[] getArray() {
                return Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
            }
}
```

i have use it like this

```
 String []array = new String[list.size()];
                            for(int i1 = 0; i1 < list.size(); i1++) 
                                {
                                array[i1] = list.get(i1);
                                System.out.println("this is from array"+array[i1]);// this statment running proper.. displays in my logcate
                                }
                            GlobalVariable.setarray(array);
                        }
```

now i want this value in another activity that extends `Frgment`
i have use it like:

```
String[] array1 = new String[1000];
        array1 = GlobalVariable.getArray();
        for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(array1[i]);
        }
```

But it crashes my application by saying ***null pointer exception*** how to use it?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to pass string array to fragment activity to fragment using getter setter method

Comment: Use a bundle for it, not a GlobalVariable class. But maybe the size your array inside GlobalVariable is not 1000, so you are maybe asking for an item at index 999 but the is nothing at 999. Do you see your println (once/more or nothing)?

Comment: Create a Constructor of fragment and Pass it in constructor and then receive it in fragment

Comment: bundle? bt how i can put it in frgmentactivity? if (selectedItem.compareTo("Recent") == 0) {
   
   
   fragment = new Recent_Activity();
  }

Comment: Don't put it in the Constructor! Use a bundle! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149802/how-to-transfer-some-data-to-another-fragment

Comment: in that how i pass? bundle

Comment: You can pass the string array by adding it to the constructor...!!

Comment: can you explain in detail?