# How to return "result" from one class to a defined class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, onactivityresult

I am working with `ViewPager` i.e on top of the `MainActivity` class and the `Viewpager` class extends fragment.

The problem is that, normally when we need a class to return some `result` then while passing the `intent` we use `startActivityforresult(intent,int)` hence it passes the result captured in the secondactivity the class from where it's been called.

**But as i am working with viewpager on top of the mainactivity and i am using `floating action button`, when i click the button to open the second activity it returns the result to the mainactivity but not the viewpager class.**

> **So my question is how can i pass the result taken from the secondactivity to my desired class?**

**Update::**
`MainActivity.java`
this is my main class which is using the intent as well as receiving the result from the second activity class `ActivityTwo`

What i have done here is

```
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
public void onActivityresult(i,j,intent){MyFragment fragment;
fragment.onActivityReusult(i,j,intent);//Here i have passes the values      
received by this class to the fragment class where i need the values but it's not working
}
```

Comment: can you call the viewpage adapter from your main activity which will call the fragment to pass the data down

Comment: yes as i am creating and calling the pager class within my mainactivity

Comment: so in onActivityResult result can you call viewPageAdapter.passData(my data) and have that pas it to the fragment. and just create pass data in your adapter

Comment: sorry i din't get you..`onActivity`??

Comment: sorry onActivityResult in the activity

Comment: ok let me try..i will keep you updated

Comment: i couldn't do...i am not able to understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75956/discussion-between-virus-and-tomer-shemesh).

Comment: The error in this case happens because the `fragment` is null, isn't it? You called `onActivityReusult` after you've just instantiated your `MyFragment`. Take a look my example again and see I got the `_fragment` from a list which I've already instantiated before in `onCreate`.

Comment: i am getting this error `Failure delivering result ResultInfo` and sir the fragment is not null

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Bundle.
Take a look at this topic : [Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149802/how-to-transfer-some-data-to-another-fragment)

```
bookDescFragment = new BookDescFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(BookDescFragment.MyVariabl, VariableValue);
myFragment.setArguments(args);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to create an `Interface` with one `method`. Then the fragment implements this `Interface`. After that, you might call this `method` in the `onActivityResult`. You just get the desired fragment in the `onActivityResult` and call the `method` from its `Interface`

EDIT:

Interface example:

```
public interface Interface_example {

    public void onActivityResult();

}
```

Fragment example:

```
public class Fragment_example extends Fragment implements Interface_example {

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult() {

        //Here you can do whatever you want

    }

}
```

Activity example:

```
public class Activity_example extends FragmentActivity {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentList;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);

        mFragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        mFragmentList.add(new Fragment_example());

        mViewPager.setAdapter(new SimpleTabPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragmentList));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Fragment _fragment = mFragmentList.get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());

        if(_fragment instanceof Fragment_example){

            // This line will call that method previously created
            ((Fragment_example) _fragment).onActivityResult();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Sir can you please describe it with a tutorial link or an example code or something