# how pass parameters between two fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-studio

i must pass two parameters from fragment to another fragment. First parameter is type String and second parameter is type int. i want pass parameters with bundle but doesn't work.

FIRST FRAGMENT

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("totale", totalAmount);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

SECOND FRAGMENT

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        TextView titolo2 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.quantità2);
        Bundle bundle=this.getArguments();
        int myInt = bundle.getInt("totale", 0);
        titolo2.setText(myInt);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);




    }
```

Comment: returning layout for Fragment after calling `getView()` to access TextView from layout probably causing issue and also `setText ` take `CharSequence` as parameter instead of `int` so use `String.valueOf` to show `int` in TextView

Comment: if i return fragment layout after getView(), Bundle bundle=this.getArguments(); is underline in red by IDE

Comment: see http://alvinalexander.com/source-code/android/android-example-oncreateview-method-fragment-class example

Comment: First Fragemnt:
`Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("message", "" + totalAmount);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);`
Second Fragment:
`int aa = getArguments().getInt("message");`

Comment: you will get the answere <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149802/how-to-transfer-some-data-to-another-fragment>?

Comment: you are trying to get the data while creating the view try it in the oncreate  function

Comment: i make this: @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

        TextView titolo2 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.quantità2);
        Bundle bundle=getArguments();
        int myInt = bundle.getInt("totale", 0);
        titolo2.setText(myInt);

        return rootView;
    }

Answer (score 0):

In first fragment write this:

```
TwoFragment fragment = new TwoFragment ();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("totale", totalAmount);
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Second fragmnent:

```
Bundle bundle=getArguments();
        int myInt = bundle.getInt("totale", 0);
        titolo2.setText(myInt);
```

Comment: r u sure u r getting totalamount value in first fragment??

Comment: YES:Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("totale", totalAmount);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

Comment: what is the name of your second fragment

Comment: public class TwoFragment extends Fragment{

Comment: on this line IDE say me error:"int myInt = bundle.getInt("totale", 0);"

Comment: this line u need to write in ur twogfragment class na

Answer (score 0):

Change Second Fragment like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

    TextView titolo2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.quantità2);
    Bundle bundle=this.getArguments();
    int myInt = bundle.getInt("totale", 0);
    titolo2.setText(myInt + "");

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: It should work then. Did it throws any exceptions or bundle doesn't have totale key?

Comment: THIS IS MY BOUNDLE:Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putInt("totale", totalAmount);
  fragment.setArguments(bundle);

Answer (score 0):

You should do the work of **second fragment** as:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
}


public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    TextView titolo2 = view.findViewById(R.id.quantità2);
    Bundle bundle=getArguments();
    int myInt = bundle.getInt("totale", 0);
    titolo2.setText(String.valueOf(myInt));
}
```

Comment: Did you instantiate second fragment's class instance as SecondFragmentClass secFragment = new SecondFragmentClass(); and then gave your bundle to the instance as secFragment.setArguments(bundle); ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a public class with two static members like this :

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static String stringValue="";
    public static int integerValue=0;
}
```

Then from your first fragment just set values like this :

```
SomeClass.stringValue="yourValue";
SomeClass.integerValue=yourIntegerValue;
```

You can use these variable from your second fragment where you want :

```
int a =SomeClass.integerValue;
String str=SomeClass.stringValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

If both fragments belong to the same activity, better to use this approach:

In activity you should save references to fragments, and all comunications between this fragments should be through activity, let's name it `BaseActivity`. For example add to activity method which will pass params to second fragment:

```
void updateSecondFragment(int param1, String param2){
    mFragment2.updateTitle(param2);
}
```

In second fragment:

```
void updateTitle(String title){
    mTextView.setText(title);
}
```

And in first fragment:

```
BaseActivity mActivity;

@Override
void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    if (activity instanceOf BaseActivity){
        mActivity = (BaseActivity) activity;
    }
}

private void updateSecondFragment(){
    if (mActivity != null){
        mActivity.updateSecondFragment(int param1, String param2);
    }
}
```