# how can i change color of image icon with the help of android coding

Tags: colors, format, size

I wanted to change color of image icon image format and image size pro-grammatically according to my requirement with the help of android code.how can i change color with the help of any specific code please suggest something.

Comment: void openImageChooser() {
        try {
            showAlertDialogWithYesNoCallBack( "Choose Type", "From Where to Pick Image", false, "Camera", "Gallery", new DialogCallBackAlert() {
                @Override
                public void dialogCallBackPositive() {
                    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                }

Comment: @Override
                public void dialogCallBackNagative() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error in Camera Alert",e.getMessage());
        }
    }

Comment: public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        try {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
                        // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));
                        setImageView(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(); }}

Comment: if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE ) {
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                    setImageView(imageBitmap);
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

Comment: public void setImageView(Bitmap bitmap){
        if(imageViewtype.equalsIgnoreCase("bannerimg")){
            bannerimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }else{
            idproof.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

Comment: public String getPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String res = null;
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        res = cursor.getString(column_index);

        cursor.close();
        return res;
    }

Comment: public  void showAlertDialogWithYesNoCallBack(String title,
String message, Boolean isCancelable, String positiveButtonTxt,String negativeButtonTxt, final DialogCallBackAlert callback) {AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.myDialog)).create();
        ///AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext(),newContextThemeWrapper(SellerActivity.this, R.style.myDialog)).create();
alertDialog.setCancelable(isCancelable);alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(isCancelable); // Setting Dialog TitlealertDialog.setTitle(title);

Comment: alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
                positiveButtonTxt, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) callback.dialogCallBackPositive() }});
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
                negativeButtonTxt, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        callback.dialogCallBackNagative()}});
        alertDialog.show(); }}

Comment: write proper i cant understand

Comment: http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/03/android-material-design-profile-screen-xml-ui-design.html

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: unable to find notification

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: pass data from one tab to aNOTHER....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943474/pass-data-from-one-design-tab-to-another-tab

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html

Comment: http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-create-android-notifications-707254/.............

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, HomeActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx); b.setAutoCancel(true) .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.setTicker("Hearty365")  .setContentTitle("Default notification")
.setContentText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")

Comment: .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
     .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
     .setContentInfo("Info");

Comment: NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());

Comment: private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 100;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the website http://www196.lunapic.com/editor/ to change the color of icon and resizing image.If you want to do from the code then try it.

```
Drawable mDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.balloons); 
mDrawable.setColorFilter(newPorterDuffColorFilter(0xffff00,
PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
```

Comment: public static int REQUEST_IMAGE_GALLERY = 101;
    public static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 101; private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 100;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";