# Send Data Between two Tab - android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-tabbed-activity

I have create Tabbed activity with two tab 
fragment a Contain edittext and fragment b  Contain listview ,and I want to send data from fragment a to fragment b ,Please add the code in full,
please help me.
Note : I do not want pass data to textview Iwant to listview

Comment: Please specify on which event you want to send the data to another fragment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass data from one design tab to another tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943474/pass-data-from-one-design-tab-to-another-tab)

Answer (score 1):

All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.
Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626004/3954185)

Comment: I do not want pass data to textview Iwant to listview

Comment: Hello friend You seem to have experience in Android programming, I have a problem and I want you to solve this problem. I have already posted my problem in stackoverflow but I can not find the right solution. Can you help me?