# How to pass String and Image value to my other fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I want to pass my String and Image value to my another Fragment.

Here is my value (These value is called from my Fragment Home)

```
private GridView grid;

    String[] nama_barang_rek = {
"Batu Bata",
"Semen Holcim",
"Cat Avitex",
"Toilet Duduk TOTO"};

    int[] gambar_barang_rek = {
R.drawable.batu_bata,
R.drawable.semen_holcim,
R.drawable.cat_avitex,
R.drawable.closet_duduk_toto};
```

And these a the code for my GridView, and i wanna pass those value to my CheckOutActivity

```
grid = (GridView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.gv_rekomendasi);
        grid.setAdapter(new CustomGrid(getActivity(), nama_barang_rek, gambar_barang_rek));
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), nama_barang_rek[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

I hope u guys could help me to fix my problem.

Comment: you can use bundle to pass the data between fragments. ex - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7149906/3912847

Answer (score 1):

if you are passing value from activity to fragment use following code before Toast message inside onItemclick

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    YourFragment mFragment = new YourFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("strValue", nama_barang_rek[position]);
    bundle.putInt("intValue",gambar_barang_rek[position]);
    mFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, mFragment);
```

where R.id.content_frame is the framelayout in xml file
if you are passing value from activity to activity use following code before Toast message inside onItemclick

```
Intent i=new Intent(firstActivity.this,secondActivity.class);
i.putString("strValue", nama_barang_rek[position]);
    i.putInt("intValue",gambar_barang_rek[position]);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sending side

```
Fragment frag = new Fragment();
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putSting("key_name", value);
data.putInt("key_name", value);
frag.setArguments(data);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.holder, frag).Commit();
```

Receiving side

```
onCreateView() {
     Bundle data = getArguments():
     If (data != null){
         // read here
     }
}
```

Comment: so we use onCreateView() on Activity? Is it just for fragment?

Comment: onCreateView is a fragment life cycle method. This is n/a for activity