# Transfer data from one fragment to another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am developing an app in which I have used bottom navigation bar so for that I had to use fragments. In my fragments, I implemented Recycler view. So My question is when I click on an item of recycler view, how can I navigate to another fragment (which is in a different item of the bottom navigation bar) and how can I transfer the data between two fragments. Please Help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transfer some data to another Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149802/how-to-transfer-some-data-to-another-fragment)

Answer (score 2):

during onClick() pass data through bundle

like that

```
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
                    Bundle bundleobj = new Bundle();
                    bundleobj.putCharSequence("key", data);


                    Fragment2 fragobj = new Fragment2();
                    fragobj.setArguments(bundleobj);
                    mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, fragobj).commit();
```

In Fragment2 class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle =getArguments();

    if(null!=bundle) {
        myData=bundle.getCharSequence("key");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In first Fragment..

```
Fragment fragment = new EditExamFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("branch_id", mDataset.get(position).getiBranchId());

          bundle.putString("exam_id",mDataset.get(position).getiExamId());
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

In Second Fragment for fetching values try below code;

```
String branch_id, exam_id ;
final Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    branch_id  = bundle.getString("branch_id");           
    exam_id  = bundle.getString("exam_id");
}
```

Comment: is there any use of adapter class?

Comment: No ...its jst exmaple of data transfer between two fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code after event listener in fragment1

```
SecondFragmentName secondFragmentName = new SecondFragmentName();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("key", "value");
                secondFragmentName.setArguments(args);
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, secondFragmentName).addToBackStack("Some string").commit();
```

To get value in Fragment2

```
String message = getArguments().getString("key");
```