# Passing getArguments have null value

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments... First is sender fragment(name is DashBoardFragment), code is...

```
 Bundle args= new Bundle();
 args.putInt("position", i+1);
 new CheckOutFragment().setArguments(args);
 fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainframe_container, new CheckOutFragment());
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And reciever fragment's(CheckOutFragment) code is...

```
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    position = bundle.getInt("position");
    Log.d("Got Position", String.valueOf(position));
```

Problem is i am not getting the value from `getArguments()`.
Guys do help me out...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149802/how-to-transfer-some-data-to-another-fragment  This will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using two different instances of `CheckOutFragment` and the second one (the one you use with your `FragmentTransaction`) is not the one you've called `setArguments()` on.

Instead, use a local variable:

```
CheckOutFragment fragment = new CheckOutFragment();
fragment.setArguments(args);
fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainframe_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: can u help me more??