# Cannot setText() of an EditText field (Android) - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, oop

When I try to setText() on an EditText I keep getting this error, I can't see where I'm going wrong. I'd like to understand the logic behind this error. I'm sure it's something small but it's really bugging me now.

> 01-25 10:20:44.267
>   14325-14325/com.example.gregsquibbs.greg_squibbs_todoapp3
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                  Process: com.example.gregsquibbs.greg_squibbs_todoapp3, PID: 14325
>                                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.gregsquibbs.greg_squibbs_todoapp3/com.example.gregsquibbs.greg_squibbs_todoapp3.EditTodo.EditTodoActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.example.gregsquibbs.greg_squibbs_todoapp3.EditTodo.EditTodoFragment.setMessage(EditTodoFragment.java:56)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.example.gregsquibbs.greg_squibbs_todoapp3.EditTodo.EditTodoActivity.onCreate(EditTodoActivity.java:41)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

This is where I create the etMessage and use setText()

```
public class EditTodoFragment extends Fragment implements EditTodoContract.View {

private EditTodoContract.Presenter presenter;
private EditText etMessage;


public EditTodoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_todo_fragment, container, false);

    System.out.println("Step 2 - Fragment check");
    etMessage = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etMessage);


    return view;
}

public void setPresenter(EditTodoContract.Presenter todoPresenter) {
    this.presenter = todoPresenter;
}

public String getMessage() {
    String message = etMessage.getText().toString();
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    etMessage.setText(message);
}
```

}

Here is the XML file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.gregsquibbs.greg_squibbs_todoapp3.EditTodo.EditTodoActivity">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rect"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textShortMessage" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSave"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:onClick="saveButtonClicked"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"


    />
```

Here is where setMessage() gets called in the activity

```
public class EditTodoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String message;
private int position;
private EditTodoFragment editTodoFragment;
private EditTodoPresenter editTodoPresenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_todo_activity);

    System.out.println("Step 1");

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.contentFrameContainer);

    if (fragment == null){
        editTodoFragment = new EditTodoFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.contentFrameContainer, editTodoFragment)
                .commit();
        editTodoPresenter = new EditTodoPresenter(editTodoFragment);
    }


    message = getIntent().getStringExtra(IntentConstants.INTENT_MESSAGE_DATA);
    position = getIntent().getIntExtra(IntentConstants.INTENT_ITEM_POSITION, -1);
    editTodoFragment.setMessage(message);

}

public void saveButtonClicked(View v) {
    if(editTodoFragment.getMessage().equals("")) {
    } else {
        String changedMessage = (editTodoFragment.getMessage());
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(IntentConstants.INTENT_CHANGED_MESSAGE, changedMessage);
        intent.putExtra(IntentConstants.INTENT_ITEM_POSITION, position);
        finish();
    }
}
```

}

---

Edit: On this line in the fragment

```
        etMessage = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.messageField);
```

When I hover over the casting (EditText) it says

> Casting 'view.findViewById(R.id.messageField)' to 'EditText' is redundant less... (⌘F1) 
>   This inspection reports unnecessary cast expressions.

I don't know whether that has anything to do with it or not.

Comment: Where do you call `setMessage`?

Comment: I pass the message from a different activity and create a new activity. I then use getIntet() and get the message and then call 

editTodoFragment.setMessage(message); 

in that activity

Comment: @Greg .xml with layout may be helpful

Comment: where do you call setMessage()?

Comment: setMessage() gets called in the activity

Comment: Are you calling setMessage() before the fragment gets inflated?

Comment: No I instantiate the fragment in the activity, then call setMessage() in the activity. I updated the post which contains all relevant files

Comment: You called fragment's method with no respect to its lifecycle. Just call setMessage inside activities onStart for example and there should be no NPE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no garrenty that `editTodoFragment.setMessage(message);` will be called after your `EditText` initialized by this line

`etMessage = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etMessage);`

In your case your code is setting text to `EditText` before it's initialized.

Best practice is send data via `Bundle` to Fragment and set Text after `EditText` is initialized.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7149906/1292557) answer

**Sample Code:**

In `EditTodoActivity`

```
 message = getIntent().getStringExtra(IntentConstants.INTENT_MESSAGE_DATA);
 if (fragment == null){
    editTodoFragment = new EditTodoFragment();
    // 
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(key, message);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.contentFrameContainer, editTodoFragment)
            .commit();
    editTodoPresenter = new EditTodoPresenter(editTodoFragment);
 }
```

In **EditTodoFragment** `onCreate`

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    message = bundle.getString(key, defaultValue);
}
```

In **EditTodoFragment** `onCreateView`

```
etMessage = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
etMessage.setText(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is that you have defined `etMessage` in other file than `edit_todo_fragment`. That's why you are not getting a compilation error, since the reference to `etMessage` exists, but it does not exists in your inflated view so thus you got the NPE.

Comment: I have inflated the right view, I just updated the post with the XML file

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from logs you're calling `setMessage` method from `onCreate` method of your activity. But the problem is Activity's `onCreate` is called earlier than Fragment's `onCreateView`, so your EditText is not initialized at that moment.

Answer (score -1):

first you have to define this **EditText** belong to witch **view** 
then, after you inflate your view you should do this.

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_todo_fragment, container, false);
    etMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
    etMessage.setText("your message...")
```

if you call set text before it, you see this error

**or**

this view (etMessage) is not in this layout (edit_todo_fragment)

Comment: This does not solve the issue. He is calling `setMessage` from somewhere else.

Comment: you mean from another activity or fragment? @MuratK.