# Reload Data on Spinner itemSelected

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-spinner

I guess i'm implementing the spinner onItemSelected inappropriately.

So i have spinner values loaded from my database. I'm trying to load data according to the spinner selected but the spinner doesn't persist and the id doesn't pass to the activity. It loads a default id of 1 instead of the selected spinner id. So i'm not sure if the spinner id is being passed. How do i check these and correct them?

```
package com.example.app;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.RetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.example.app.Config;
import com.example.app.R;
import com.example.app.fragment.FragmentCategory;
import com.example.app.fragment.FragmentFavorite;
import com.example.app.fragment.FragmentProfile;
import com.example.app.fragment.FragmentRecent;
import com.example.app.fragment.FragmentVideo;
import com.example.app.models.Constituency;
import com.example.app.utils.AppBarLayoutBehavior;
import com.example.app.utils.Constant;
import com.example.app.utils.GDPR;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


String URL="https://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/get_constituency_index/?api_key="+ 
 Config.API_KEY;

private long exitTime = 0;
MyApplication myApplication;
View view;
private BottomNavigationView navigation;
public ViewPager viewPager;
private Toolbar toolbar;
MenuItem prevMenuItem;
int pager_number = 5;
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
Spinner mySpinner;
ArrayList<String> spinnerConstituencyName;
int spinConstID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Set Font
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Arkhip_font.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    if (Config.ENABLE_RTL_MODE) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        }
    }

    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_appbar_layout);
    ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams()).setBehavior(new AppBarLayoutBehavior());

    myApplication = MyApplication.getInstance();

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

    spinnerConstituencyName = new ArrayList<>();
    mySpinner = findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
    loadSpinnerData(URL);

    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        int check = 0;
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            /*String spinConstituency = mySpinner.getItemAtPosition(mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), spinConstituency, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

            if ( ++check > 1 ){

                PrefManager prefManager = new PrefManager(MainActivity.this);
                prefManager.writeString("" + spinConstID);
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mySpinner.getItemAtPosition(mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString() + " Showing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }

    });


    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(pager_number);

    navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_category:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_video:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_favorite:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_profile:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (prevMenuItem != null) {
                prevMenuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                navigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
            }
            navigation.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
            prevMenuItem = navigation.getMenu().getItem(position);

            if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_category));
            } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
                toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_video));
            } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 3) {
                toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_favorite));
            } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 4) {
                toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_favorite));
            } else {
                toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    if (Config.ENABLE_RTL_MODE) {
        viewPager.setRotationY(180);
    }

    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // checking for type intent filter
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Constant.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                // now subscribe to global topic to receive app wide notifications
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Constant.TOPIC_GLOBAL);

            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constant.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                // new push notification is received
                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    final String imageUrl = intent.getStringExtra("image");
    final long nid = intent.getLongExtra("id", 0);
    final String link = intent.getStringExtra("link");

    if (message != null) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        View mView = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_notif, null);

        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alert.setView(mView);

        final TextView notification_title = mView.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
        final TextView notification_message = mView.findViewById(R.id.news_message);
        final ImageView notification_image = mView.findViewById(R.id.news_image);

        if (imageUrl.endsWith(".jpg") || imageUrl.endsWith(".jpeg") || imageUrl.endsWith(".png") || imageUrl.endsWith(".gif")) {
            notification_title.setText(message);
            notification_message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(imageUrl.replace(" ", "%20"))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail)
                    .resize(200, 200)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(notification_image);

            alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_read_more, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityNotificationDetail.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id", nid);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_dismiss, null);

        } else {
            notification_title.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

            notification_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            notification_message.setText(message);

            notification_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "link : " + link, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (!link.equals("")) {
                alert.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent open = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link));
                        startActivity(open);
                    }
                });
                alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_dismiss, null);
            } else {
                alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, null);
            }
        }

        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.show();

    }

    GDPR.updateConsentStatus(this);

}

public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentRecent();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentCategory();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentVideo();
            case 3:
                return new FragmentFavorite();
            case 4:
                return new FragmentProfile();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pager_number;
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.search:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivitySearch.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() != 0) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem((0), true);
    } else {
        exitApp();
    }
}

public void exitApp() {
    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - exitTime) > 2000) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.press_again_to_exit), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        exitTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

private int getIndex(Spinner spinner, String myString){

    int index = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<spinner.getCount();i++){
        if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals(myString)){
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

private void loadSpinnerData(String url) {
    RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);

                if(jsonObject.getString("status").equals("ok")){
                    JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("constituencies");

                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String spinConstituency=jsonObject1.getString("constituency_name");
                        spinConstID = jsonObject1.getInt("const_id");
                        spinnerConstituencyName.add(spinConstituency);
                    }
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                            R.layout.custom_spinner_item, spinnerConstituencyName){
                    @Override
                    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                                ViewGroup parent) {
                        View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                        TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                        if(position%2 == 1) {
                            // Set the item background color
                            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#910D3F"));
                        }
                        else {
                            // Set the alternate item background color
                            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#41061C"));
                        }
                        return view;
                    }
                };

                mySpinner.setPrompt("Select Your Constituency");
                myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_item);
                mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                //RECEIVE DATA VIA INTENT
                Intent i = getIntent();
                String name = i.getStringExtra("NAME_KEY");

                mySpinner.setSelection(getIndex(mySpinner, name));

            }catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });


    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem (On Spinner Item selection)

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mySpinner.getItemAtPosition(mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString() + " Showing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
```

**You are starting current activity as new and finish current activity, it means when you select any of items from spinner it will start a new activity and your on create executed again and again, so please place other logic or you can send your values in your activity using `intent.putextra()` and check in oncreate for null and if values is not null you can set `spinner.setSelected(Your Position)`. For Fragment You can use

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(ComingSoonFragment.this).attach(ComingSoonFragment.this).commit();
```

for refresh your fragment and [pass your data with bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149802/how-to-transfer-some-data-to-another-fragment) and check for null if your bundle is null then use your code for defalt and if not null then set your data according to your id.

**

Thanks

Comment: How do i reload the fragment which shows the data for that activity using the id of the selected spinner item

Answer (score -1):

In your spinner inside OnItemSelectedListener use parent.getItemAtPosition(position) to get the correct value

```
 mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
    "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       //Do your staff here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

});
```