# setArguments() in Fragment and onCreate()

Tags: android, android-fragments

If I create a new `Fragment` and then I set arguments to it can I rely on those arguments always being  available for me in the `onCreate()` of the `Fragment`? If yes, how do they do it? If not how I'am I supposed to communicate if they don't want us to write new constructors?

Comment: `how do they do it` - how they do what? the arguments are available though the whole fragment's lifecycle

Comment: @Blackbelt in my head I'm thinking `onCreate()` is immediately called so if I have the `setArguments()` on the next line how are they available still on the `onCreate()`?

Comment: it is not . setArguments has to be called after you instante the fragment and before committing a transaction. onCreate gets called after you commit a transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your arguments are avaialble in onCreate method. Please check it out this response in order to see how to pass arguments to fragments: [How to transfer some data to another Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149802/how-to-transfer-some-data-to-another-fragment)

Another way to communicate with the fragment is via a interface that your activity is implementing and you pass it as a reference to your fragment, in onAttach method. More info:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

[Basic Communication between two fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700798/basic-communication-between-two-fragments)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way any fragment to set argument and get argument..

```
// pass parameter to pass into bundle
public static NewMessageFragment newInstance(UserData userData) {
    NewMessageFragment newMessageFragment = new NewMessageFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE_USER_VO, userData);
    newMessageFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return newMessageFragment;
}

// get value.
private void extractArguments() {
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        userData = bundle.getParcelable(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE_USER_VO);
    }
}
```

**extractArguments()** method called into **onCreateView()** method.