# Passing Data between fragments while using Bottom Navigation

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, reference

I need recommandation or explanation because i am little bit lost

I am using bottom navigation with 3 fragments

First one is called `RestaurantFragment` which contains an `itemsList` of restaurants that i am getting from the server and loading this data to a `recycler view`

And the second one is `FavorisFragment` which contains a `subList` of the fist `itemList` and i have that `subList` in the `itemAdapter` class

So i have searched how could i pass the data between my two fragments ( or between recyclerView and a fragment ) , but i only found one that send data from fragment to an other using `Bundle`

> the issue is that the fragment change is hapening in the `MainActivity`

i have a solution which works pretty fine but i think it is memory consuming

this is my MainActivity :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new RestaurantFragment()).commit();
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);

    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment ;

                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.nav_restaurant :

                            selectedFragment=new RestaurantFragment() ;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_favoris :
                            selectedFragment=new FavorisFragment() ;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_client :
                            selectedFragment=new ClientFragment() ;
                            break;
                        default:
                            selectedFragment=new RestaurantFragment() ;
                    }

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,selectedFragment).commit();
                    Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
                    return true ;


                }
            };


}
```

and i am using MyApplication to hold the two lists the one that i get from the server and the subList that the client choose as favorite

Here MyApplication

```
import android.app.Application;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }
    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }
    private ArrayList<RecyclerItem> itemList;
    private ArrayList<RecyclerItem> recyclerData;

    public ArrayList<RecyclerItem> getRecyclerData(){
        return recyclerData;
    }

    public void setRecyclerData(ArrayList<RecyclerItem> recyclerData){
        this.recyclerData=recyclerData;
    }

    public ArrayList<RecyclerItem> getItemList(){
        return itemList;
    }

    public void setItemList(ArrayList<RecyclerItem> itemList){
        this.itemList=itemList;
    }

    public void deletAll(){
        this.itemList.clear();
    }
}
```

in `itemAdapter` i am using this to send data :

```
 MyApplication.getInstance().setItemList(itemListFavoris);
```

and in `FavorisFragment` i am using this to get data :

```
        itemList = MyApplication.getInstance().getItemList();
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Your solution is not really a good one. Your "Application" class is not (and should not) be used to maintain two array lists or anything related. Communication between fragments and between components can be done in different ways, but the recommended approach nowadays is to use a ViewModel. Start here in the  [Android Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/) documentation, and more specifically [ViewModels](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

Comment: @MartinMarconcini i know my solution is not good that's why i am asking , i will take a look on the two links you mentionned , thank you

Comment: Viewmodel is the best way to share the data between fragments. Checkout this blog on how to implement it. Also you can use room database.

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149802/how-to-transfer-some-data-to-another-fragment

Comment: @Danialclarc already checked , as you can see i mentionned that i cannot use Bundle in my case since changing fragments is hapening in mainActivity not in the fragment nor in the itemAdapter