# How to get the values of a spinner into a different fragment?

Tags: java, android, tabs, fragment

I'm trying to pass the value of a spinner into a different fragment so that it can be used in a different fragment to convert it to a different unit. I have the code here. I have an onitemselected method which takes the value of the spinner and displays it at the bottom of the application.

Any help would be appreciated.

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

```
    String[] values =
            {"Select Units:", "Miles", "Kilometers", "Meters", "Yards",};
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);




    String[] values1=
            {"Select Units:", "Miles", "Kilometers", "Meters", "Yards",};
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values1);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    button1 =view.findViewById(R.id.button_confirm);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CharSequence input = spinner.
        }
    });
    return view;



}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to transfer some data to another Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149802/how-to-transfer-some-data-to-another-fragment)

In your fragment that creates the data, store it in a bundle and send it to the next fragment via arguments, then in a method which takes a bundle (like onCreateView), use the value that is found in the bundle.

Comment: what specific thing in the fragment would i store into the bundle to then send it to the next fragment?