# How to pass data from fragment to activity with bundle

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a search view on my Main Activity, i want to pass the submitted string from MainActivity to SearchFragment.

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("searchTitle", query);
   SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
   searchFragment.setArguments(bundle);

   Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
   startActivity(mIntent);

   return true;
}
```

But i get NullPointerException when i try to get the data in the SearchFragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    strText = getArguments().getString("searchTitle");

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
}
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149802/how-to-transfer-some-data-to-another-fragment ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transfer some data to another Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149802/how-to-transfer-some-data-to-another-fragment)

Comment: @P.Juni No, it always return a null value

Comment: I think you should add data to your Intent from MainActivity to SearchActivity. Then if you get data in SearchActivity you should add data to bundle and create SearchFragment with bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

In your MainActivity.

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("searchTitle", query);
    SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
    searchFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);

    // Add this line.
    mIntent.putExtra("key", "value");

    startActivity(mIntent);
    return true;
}
```

In your SearchActivity.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView([layout_name])

    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    // Put data respected to your data type.
    bundle.putString("key", getIntent().getStringExtra("key"));
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    // Add new fragment
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add([container_id], fragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()
}
```

In your Fragment.

```
@Override
public onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String value = getArguments().getString("key");
}
```

Comment: does not work, it still generates NullPointerException on the line code                    
" strText = getArguments (). getString ("key"); "

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data through bundle, at least you should put this bundle in your intent

```
mIntent.putExtras(bundle)
```

Than you can get it through this

```
getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("searchTitle")
```