# Sending data from recyclerview to fragment without intarface in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm studying kotlin, and am stuck about recyclerview.
The task is simple: show data from recycler (inside activity) item clicked inside a fragment.

**The Model:**

```
data class MyModel (
val info1:String,
val info2:String,
val info3:String)
```

the `recyclerView` is implemented using the idea I saw in Antonio's book (kotlin for android developers) - no **intarface** is used:

```
class RecyclerAdapter(
val myList:List<MyModel>,
val listener:(MyModel)->Unit):RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val itemViewholder = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item,parent,false)
    return MyViewHolder(itemViewholder)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(myList[position],listener)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return myList.count()
}

class MyViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    fun bind(list:MyModel,itemListener: (MyModel) -> Unit) = with(itemView){
        recycler_infor1.text = list.info1
        recicler_infor2.text = list.info2
        setOnClickListener { itemListener(list) }
    }
}}
```

**In Activity:**

```
with(my_recyclerView){
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        adapter = RecyclerAdapter(fakeItens()){
            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                replace(R.id.fragment_container,FragmentDetail()).addToBackStack(null)
            }
        }

}
```

When the app is run, the `recyclerView` shows in each item the first and second information as well.
Now, I need to show these informations and the third infor inside a Fragment that has three `textView`:

```
android:id="@+id/frag_infor1"
android:id="@+id/frag_infor2"
android:id="@+id/frag_infor3"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you have to pass MyModel object to the destination fragment as a bundle, I believe you this will answer your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149802/how-to-transfer-some-data-to-another-fragment

Comment: thank's @null_override. Solution in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's to [null_override](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13296516/null-override), I found my solution:

1 - make `MyModel` `Parcelable`

```
data class MyModel(val info1:String?,
                   val info2:String?,
                   val info3:String?
):Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString()
    )


    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(info1)
        parcel.writeString(info2)
        parcel.writeString(info3)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<MyModel> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): MyModel {
            return MyModel(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<MyModel?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }

}
```

2 - passing to `bundle` and set argument to `Fragment` using `apply` in both

```
with(my_recyclerView){
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            adapter = RecyclerAdapter(fakeItens()){
                val bundle = Bundle().apply { putParcelable("Key", it) }
                supportFragmentManager.commit {
                    replace(R.id.fragment_container,FragmentDetail().apply { arguments = bundle }).addToBackStack(null)
                }
            }

        }
```

3  - get data in `Fragment`

```
lateinit var data:MyModel
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
     super.onAttach(context)
     arguments?.getParcelable<MyModel>("Key").let {
          if (it != null) {
              data = it
          }
           
      }
  }
```

4 - bind `views`

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        frag_infor1.text = data.info1
        frag_infor2.text = data.info2
        frag_infor3.text = data.info3
}
```

Comment: Actually I just edited your question. So, say thanks to  **ArMot**