# Same fragment layout different ImageView and text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a fragment that contains 3 different ImageButtons, that links to a new fragment with some information.

All info.fragments have the same layout, only different is the image and text.

I would like to reuse the layout on the info.fragment and pass the image and text value instead. ex. StarImage and StarText and the same with MusicImage and MusicText.

*This is my first project in AndroidStudio.*

[startFragment and 2 info.Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSwpW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a int (or a Enum index) to your destination Fragment as a Bundle and retrieve it in your `onCreateView` to set your text and image according to the received number.

Check out this answer to see an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21486451/11407290