# getting null value when passing value from activity to fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

How do i pass a value from an `Activity` to a `Fragment`?

I understand that i can use `setArgument` in my `Activity` and `getArgument` in `Fragment`. But i did it with no luck. The value still returns as null.

---

Activity

```
public class nfc_activity extends Activity {
    private ImageView mCardView;
    MyFragmentA f2;
    public static String itemname;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         Button goButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go);
            goButton.setOnClickListener(mGoListener);


        }

       private OnClickListener mGoListener = new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // Here we start up the main entry point of our redirection
                // example.
                String itemname ="1";

                  MyFragmentA fragment = new MyFragmentA();
                Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
                bundle2.putString("key", itemname);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle2);

            }
        };

}
```

---

Fragment

```
public class MyFragmentA extends Fragment {



 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
  if (bundle != null) {
      String hello = bundle.getString("key", defaultValue);
      System.out.println(hello);
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass data between fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments)

Comment: What is the API level you have mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show how your fragment is attached to the activity, but you have to make sure the arguments are set on the fragment *before* you attach it for them to be available in onCreateView.

Comment: something like :   Fragment fragment = (Fragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pager);
             Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
              bundle2.putString("key", itemname);  
              fragment.setArguments(bundle2);  i got nullpointerexception from using this. please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Tag to identify your Fragment and findFragmentByTag to retrieve it?
It seems to me cleaner than using findFragmentById which actually look for the id of the inflated XML layout or the id of the container layout!