# Communicating between a fragment and an activity - best practices

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, communication

This question is mostly to solicit opinions on the best way to handle my app.  I have three fragments being handled by one activity.  Fragment A has one clickable element the photo and Fragment B has 4 clickable elements the buttons.  The other fragment just displays details when the photo is clicked.  I am using ActionBarSherlock.

[image: Screen shot]

The forward and back buttons need to change the photo to the next or previous poses, respectively.  I could keep the photo and the buttons in the same fragment, but wanted to keep them separate in case I wanted to rearrange them in a tablet.

I need some advice - should I combine Fragments A and B?  If not, I will need to figure out how to implement an interface for 3 clickable items.

I considered using Roboguice, but I am already extending using SherlockFragmentActivity so that's a no go.  I saw mention of Otto, but I didn't see good tutorials on how to include in a project. What do you think best design practice should be?

I also need help figuring out how to communicate between a fragment and an activity.  I'd like to keep some data "global" in the application, like the pose id.  Is there some example code I can see besides the stock android developer's information?  That is not all that helpful.

BTW, I'm already storing all the information about each pose in a SQLite database.  That's the easy part.

Comment: Actually you can use Rogoguice with ActionbarSherlock, take a look at https://github.com/rtyley/roboguice-sherlock.

Comment: Otto is even simpler, is packaged as a standalone .jar file which you can place in the libs/ folder of your of your application.

Comment: @rubenlop88 adding a library just to pass some data from Fragment to Activity?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The easiest way to communicate between your activity and fragments is using interfaces. The idea is basically to define an interface inside a given fragment A and let the activity implement that interface.

Once it has implemented that interface, you could do anything you want in the method it overrides.

The other important part of the interface is that you have to call the abstract method from your fragment and remember to cast it to your activity. It should catch a ClassCastException if not done correctly.

There is a good tutorial on [Simple Developer Blog](http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/) on how to do exactly this kind of thing.

I hope this was helpful to you!

Comment: Does anyone know why the example on the android developers page regarding use of an alert dialog doesn't use an interface to communicate with the activity?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#AlertDialog

Comment: @cjayem13 In some cases, you might need a fragment to share events with the activity, A good way to do that is to define a callback interface, Perhaps you can look at this [Communicating with the Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)

Comment: Interfaces are good. But for looser coupling, use broadcast listeners.

Comment: Sure, but what happens when your activity winds up providing several distinct services to a fragment because the fragment can't do lots of Context-ey things by itself? I reached the point of having my activity implement 4 different interfaces for communicating with fragments before throwing my hands up and just letting the fragments know about the activity, because those fragments aren't going to be parented in a different activity ever in my case, and if they did I'd probably have to fix other stuff to make that work smoothly anyway.

Comment: The modern approach would be to use Events which actually decouples your project code and this answer being from 2014, although works to an extent, should not be the only solution to this scenario!

Comment: @Eenvincible Yes you are right please update your answer accordingly for people who come here in the future.

Comment: What is proposed here is doing things backward - Activity has to implement the interface and fragments have to guess which interfaces Activity implements? Listener approach is much more flexible.

Comment: Architecture components are also a new and clean way to handle communication with loose coupling.

Comment: @Eenvincible the link to Simple Developer Blog is dead. Actually, the server of the blog is not found.

Comment: You might have to switch to google DNS servers! The site is working!

Answer (score 24):

The suggested method for communicating between fragments is to use callbacks\listeners that are managed by your main Activity.

I think the code on this page is pretty clear:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

You can also reference the IO 2012 Schedule app, which is designed to be a de-facto reference app.  It can be found here:
http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

Also, here is a SO question with good info:
[How to pass data between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments)

Answer (score 22):

It is implemented by a Callback interface:

> First of all, we have to make an interface:

```
public interface UpdateFrag {
     void updatefrag();
}
```

> In the Activity do the following code:

```
UpdateFrag updatfrag ;

public void updateApi(UpdateFrag listener) {
        updatfrag = listener;
}
```

> from the event from where the callback has to fire in the Activity:

```
updatfrag.updatefrag();
```

> In the Fragment implement the interface in `CreateView` do the
>   following code:

```
 ((Home)getActivity()).updateApi(new UpdateFrag() {
        @Override
        public void updatefrag() {
              .....your stuff......
        }
 });
```

Comment: This works nicely - thanks for sharing good explanation :)

Comment: One of the best answers on the net. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 9):

To communicate between an `Activity` and `Fragment`s, there are several options, but after lots of reading and many experiences, I found out that it could be resumed this way:

- `Activity` wants to communicate with child `Fragment` => Simply write public methods in your `Fragment` class, and let the `Activity` call them
- `Fragment` wants to communicate with the parent `Activity` => This requires a bit more of work, as the official Android link https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating suggests, it would be a great idea to define an `interface` that will be implemented by the `Activity`, and which will establish a contract for any `Activity` that wants to communicate with that `Fragment`. For example, if you have `FragmentA`, which wants to communicate with any `activity` that includes it, then define the `FragmentAInterface` which will define what method can the `FragmentA` call for the `activities` that decide to use it.
- A `Fragment` wants to communicate with other `Fragment` => This is the case where you get the most 'complicated' situation. Since you could potentially need to pass data from FragmentA to FragmentB and viceversa, that could lead us to defining 2 interfaces, `FragmentAInterface` which will be implemented by `FragmentB` and `FragmentAInterface` which will be implemented by `FragmentA`. That will start making things messy. And imagine if you have a few more `Fragment`s on place, and even the parent `activity` wants to communicate with them. Well, this case is a perfect moment to establish a shared `ViewModel` for the `activity` and it's `fragment`s. More info here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel . Basically, you need to define a `SharedViewModel` class, that has all the data you want to share between the `activity` and the `fragments` that will be in need of communicating data among them.

The `ViewModel` case, makes things pretty simpler at the end, since you don't have to add extra logic that makes things dirty in the code and messy. Plus it will allow you to separate the gathering (through calls to an SQLite Database or an API) of data from the `Controller` (`activities` and `fragments`).

Answer (score 5):

I made a annotation library that can do the cast for you. check this out.
https://github.com/zeroarst/callbackfragment/

```
@CallbackFragment
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Callback
    interface FragmentCallback {
       void onClickButton(MyFragment fragment);
    }    
    private FragmentCallback mCallback;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bt1
                mCallback.onClickButton(this);
                break;
            case R.id.bt2
                // Because we give mandatory = false so this might be null if not implemented by the host.
                if (mCallbackNotForce != null)
                mCallbackNotForce.onClickButton(this);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

It then generates a subclass of your fragment. And just add it to FragmentManager.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.FragmentCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.lo_fragm_container, MyFragmentCallbackable.create(), "MY_FRAGM")
            .commit();
    }

    Toast mToast;

    @Override
    public void onClickButton(MyFragment fragment) {
        if (mToast != null)
            mToast.cancel();
        mToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Callback from " + fragment.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        mToast.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Google Recommended Method**

If you take a look at [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#kotlin) you can see that Google suggests you use the `ViewModel` to share data between `Fragment` and `Activity`.

Add this dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activity_version"
```

First, define the `ViewModel` you are going to use to pass data.

```
class ItemViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val mutableSelectedItem = MutableLiveData<Item>()
    val selectedItem: LiveData<Item> get() = mutableSelectedItem

    fun selectItem(item: Item) {
        mutableSelectedItem.value = item
    }
}
```

Second, instantiate the `ViewModel` inside the `Activity`.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // Using the viewModels() Kotlin property delegate from the activity-ktx
    // artifact to retrieve the ViewModel in the activity scope
    private val viewModel: ItemViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.selectedItem.observe(this, Observer { item ->
            // Perform an action with the latest item data
        })
    }
}
```

Third, instantiate the `ViewModel` inside the `Fragment`.

```
class ListFragment : Fragment() {
    // Using the activityViewModels() Kotlin property delegate from the
    // fragment-ktx artifact to retrieve the ViewModel in the activity scope
    private val viewModel: ItemViewModel by activityViewModels()

    // Called when the item is clicked
    fun onItemClicked(item: Item) {
        // Set a new item
        viewModel.selectItem(item)
    }
}
```

You can now edit this code creating new observers or settings methods.

Answer (score 2):

There are severals ways to communicate between activities, fragments, services etc. The obvious one is to communicate using interfaces. However, it is not a productive way to communicate. You have to implement the listeners etc.

My suggestion is to use an event bus. Event bus is a publish/subscribe pattern implementation.

You can subscribe to events in your activity and then you can post that events in your fragments etc.

Here [on my blog post](http://gunhansancar.com/ease-communication-between-activities-fragments-services/) you can find more detail about this pattern and also [an example project](https://github.com/gunhansancar/eventbus-example/tree/master) to show the usage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I really understood what you want to do, but the suggested way to communicate between fragments is to use callbacks with the Activity, never directly between fragments. See here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Yeah, that way seems confusing, I have 2 fragments that need to somehow communicate with each other through the activity.  Is there a better tutorial out there on how to do this?

Comment: @KristyWelsh : I wonder if you have developed your own concept of what `Fragments` really are and how they work rather than grasped the actual concept of the `Fragment` design goal. The concept of communicating with the `Activity` using `interfaces` is no different from having an `Activity` implement `View.OnClickListener` so a `Button` press results in an item being added to a `ListView` (for example). You might have an `Activity` with FragmentA and FragmentB but NOT FragmentC - in this case, the concept of having FragmentA "know" how to talk to FragmentC directly is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can create declare a public interface with a function declaration in the fragment and implement the interface in the activity. Then you can call the function from the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Intents to communicate actions back to the main activity. The main activity is listening to these by overriding onNewIntent(Intent intent). The main activity translates these actions to the corresponding fragments for example.

So you can do something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    public static final String INTENT_ACTION_SHOW_FOO = "show_foo";
    public static final String INTENT_ACTION_SHOW_BAR = "show_bar";


   @Override
   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        routeIntent(intent);
   }

  private void routeIntent(Intent intent) {
       String action = intent.getAction();
       if (action != null) {               
            switch (action) {
            case INTENT_ACTION_SHOW_FOO:
                // for example show the corresponding fragment
                loadFragment(FooFragment);
                break;
            case INTENT_ACTION_SHOW_BAR:
                loadFragment(BarFragment);
                break;               
        }
    }
}
```

Then inside any fragment to show the foo fragment:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.setAction(INTENT_ACTION_SHOW_FOO);
// Prevent activity to be re-instantiated if it is already running.
// Instead, the onNewEvent() is triggered
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -3):

There is the latest techniques to communicate fragment to activity without any interface follow the steps
Step 1- Add the dependency in gradle

implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-rc01'

Comment: Please provide an example. You just defined some dependency. How is it used? What is different?