# Android: How do I change a value that is defined in the xml within the java code

Tags: android

I have multiple tabs with text on them. I have another tab which is responsible for holding the GUI elements to change the value of the default text size. I already have a default value set in the xml files. How might I go about doing this, creating a variable that is accessible to all activities?

Comment: You can access xml values using getResources(). check the resources class documentation on the respective API's. In your case, it might be getInteger().

Comment: I usegetView().findViewById(R.dimen.text_size), but then how do I change that?

Comment: You should be using getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size) to get the value set. findViewById will only find the Views and not dimentions.

Answer (score 0):

Question kind of vague but anyway here is my answer

```
    <resources>
         <integer-array name="UserBases">
              <item>2</item>
              <item>8</item>
              <item>10</item>
              <item>16</item>
         </integer-array>
    </resources>

Resources r = getResources();
int[] bases = r.getIntArray(R.array.UserBases)
```

Use the `bases` array to pic your size

Here's the way to do it [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: Yes but how do I make it consistent throughout?

Comment: You have to let them all know what <item>xxx</item> to use. You could create an interface that will tell everyone what to do. What we are talking about now is standard communication among Activities and fragment. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247954/communicating-between-a-fragment-and-an-activity-best-practices)