# error when pass data between fragments through the mainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

in the below code, i have a mainActivity that hosts two `fragments` `Frag1` and `Frag2` as shown below, `Frag1` implements `sensorEventListener` and when the `button` in the `Frag1` is clicked the sensor reading should pass to `Frag2`.

to do so, I created an interface `onSendListener` which is in `onAttch` is set to `sendValues = (onSendListener) activity;`. and the `mainActivity` implements `onSendListener` as shown in the code of the `mainActivity` posted below, and in `onSendListener` i pass the readings to `Frag2`.

at run time i receive the below posted `logCat` errors.

please let me know what i am missing ro doing wrong.

** MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements onSendListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
}

/**
 * to send values from frag1 to frag2 through mainActivity. use bundle.
 */
@Override
public void onSendValues(float x, float y, float z) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putFloat("x", x);
    b.putFloat("y", y);
    b.putFloat("z", z);

    Frag2 frag2 = new Frag2();
    frag2.setArguments(b);
}
```

}

**Frag1 **:

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener {

private SensorManager sensorManager;
TextView tvAccX;
TextView tvAccY;
TextView tvAccZ;

private float x = 0.0f;
private float y = 0.0f;
private float z = 0.0f;

private void setAccX(float x) {
    this.x = x;
}
private float getAccX() {
    return this.x;
}

private void setAccY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
}
private float getAccY() {
    return this.y;
}

private void setAccZ(float z) {
    this.z = z;
}
private float getAccZ() {
    return this.z;
}

Button btnSend;
onSendListener sendValues;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);

    sendValues = (onSendListener) activity;
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_1, container, false);

    tvAccX = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_accX_value);
    tvAccY = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_accY_value);
    tvAccZ = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_accZ_value);
    btnSend = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
        showAccReadings(event);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

private void showAccReadings(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float[] values = event.values;

    float x = values[0];
    float y = values[1];
    float z = values[2];

    setAccX(x);
    setAccY(y);
    setAccZ(z);

    tvAccX.setText(String.valueOf(x));
    tvAccY.setText(String.valueOf(y));
    tvAccZ.setText(String.valueOf(z));
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    Sensor accSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accSensor, sensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sendValues.onSendValues(getAccX(), getAccY(), getAccZ());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

}

**Frag2 **:

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment {

float x;
float y;
float z;

TextView tvX;
TextView tvY;
TextView tvZ;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    x = getArguments().getFloat("x");
    y = getArguments().getFloat("y");
    z = getArguments().getFloat("z");

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_2, container, false);

    tvX = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_accX2_label);
    tvY = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_accY2_label);
    tvZ = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_accZ2_label);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    tvX.setText(String.valueOf(x));
    tvY.setText(String.valueOf(y));
    tvZ.setText(String.valueOf(z));
}
```

}

** mainActivity.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}">

<fragment
    android:name="com.example.fragmentcommunication_00.Frag1"
    android:id="@+id/frag_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<fragment
    android:name="com.example.fragmentcommunication_00.Frag2"
    android:id="@+id/frag_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/frag_1"/>
```

** Frag1.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_accX_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="Acc[X]: "/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_accX_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_accX_label"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_accY_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_accX_label"
    android:text="Acc[Y]: "/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_accY_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv_accY_label"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_accX_label"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_accZ_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_accY_label"
    android:text="Acc[Z]: "/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_accZ_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv_accZ_label"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_accY_label"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn_send"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_accZ_label"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="send to frag_2"/>
```

**Frag2.xml **:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_accX2_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="Acc[X]: "/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_accY2_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_accX2_label"
    android:text="Acc[Y]: "/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_accZ2_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_accY2_label"
    android:text="Acc[Z]: "/>
```

**logCat**:

```
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546): Process: com.example.fragmentcommunication_00, PID: 4546
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragmentcommunication_00/com.example.fragmentcommunication_00.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:340)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1973)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at com.example.fragmentcommunication_00.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     ... 11 more
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at com.example.fragmentcommunication_00.Frag2.onCreateView(Frag2.java:25)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
0   1-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4935)
01-26 10:51:24.416: E/AndroidRuntime(4546):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutI    nflater.java:695)
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the system can't create the second fragment because it needs arguments that you set at different time, not at the time when you create layout. ActivityManager calls onCreate() in your Activity, and onCreate() and onCreateView() in your fragments. But call for method onSendValues() that sets arguments doesn't happen at the time of creation.

Setting arguments to the fragment is not the solution for dynamic communication between fragments. It works only for the initial creation of your views

You have to create public method in your second fragment and call it from activity when you need to pass data from activity to it. So the scheme of communication is: Fragment1 via interface calls method in activity -> activity calls method in your Fragment2

You can check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28117138/3383038