# How I can communicate a fragment that was added programmatically with an activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

As I can communicate a fragment that was added programmatically with an activity and that activity also can communicate with the fragment.

**Activity**

[image: Activity]

**Fragment added programmatically**

[image: Fragment added programmatically]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicating between a fragment and an activity - best practices.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247954/communicating-between-a-fragment-and-an-activity-best-practices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Activity->Fragment: `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByXX()`
- Fragment->Activity: `getActivity()`

Also it is a common practice to use Interface to communicate between them.
See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html