# Activity not called from intent in onActivityCreated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-fragmentactivity

I have button in my Tab1.java, by clicking the button, it will call another class say Custom.java, But i am facing error:

**`"Intent cannot be resolved to a type"`**

I searched a lot but did not find any helpful post regarding this.
Please Help me !

Tab1.java

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment
{
    ListView lv;
    int FIRST_OPTION = 1;
    int SECOND_OPTION = 2;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Button b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button4);
    registerForContextMenu(b);

    Button bi = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button5);
    registerForContextMenu(bi);

    Button setting = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.setting);
    setting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Custom.class));             
        }
    });

    b.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            menu.add(0, FIRST_OPTION, 0, "Activate");

                }
    });
bi.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            menu.add(0, SECOND_OPTION, 0, "Activate");
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if(itemId == FIRST_OPTION){
        //Normal_Mode nm = new Normal_Mode();
        //nm.activateNormal(getApplicationContext());
    Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Normal Mode Activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return true;

    }
    else if(itemId == SECOND_OPTION){
        //Silent_Mode sm = new Silent_Mode();
        //sm.activateSilent(getApplicationContext());
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Silent Mode Activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;            
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
 }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,
        @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile,container,false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Custom.java

```
public class Custom extends Activity{

    private SeekBar mediaVlmSeekBar = null;
    private AudioManager audioManager = null;
    private boolean mphoneisVib;
    Ringtone ringtone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);  
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_sett);
        initControls();

        audioManager= (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

        setButtonClickListener();

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent inte = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
                inte.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, 
                        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
                //String title= ringtone.getTitle(this);
            inte.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Sle");

                startActivityForResult(inte, 5);
            }           
        });     
    }

   /********************* Code For VIbration *******************************/

    private void setButtonClickListener() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        tb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(mphoneisVib){
                    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                mphoneisVib=false;
            Toast toast=    Toast.makeText(Custom.this, "Vibration Off !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                }
                else{

                    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);

                    mphoneisVib=true;

                    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(Custom.this, "Vibration On !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();                   
                }                   
            }
        });
    }
    /********************          End        *************************/

    /******************** Code For Volume Seekbar *********************/
    private void initControls() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
        mediaVlmSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        mediaVlmSeekBar.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)); 
        //Set the progress with current Media Volume 
        mediaVlmSeekBar.setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

        try { mediaVlmSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {    
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {         }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);                   
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {                 
            } 
        });

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {e.printStackTrace(); } 
    }
             /***********************  End  ***************************/
```

Comment: post your whole log.

Comment: Post Custom class source code

Comment: @AkashSingh
i have posted my whole code

Comment: @astinx
See updated code

Answer (score 1):

Hye there, Kindly try this way.

```
setting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
   /startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Custom.class));   
    Intent intent = new Intent((Tab1)getActivity(), Custom.class);
    (Tab1)getActivity().startActivity(intent);    

    }
});
```

Comment: Hurrah !! i solved myself
I just imported a package
**import android.content.Intent;**
And refreshed.

Comment: :D :D
koi baat nai yaar..
Apne koshish to ki na.
I need some another help.
Guide kar do gay.

Comment: i am new on android, working on project .Need your help

Comment: yup buddy i can help u on reasonable timing.! :)

Comment: Thanx bhayya :-).. how can i contact you !  I mean skype or personal contact number or ..

Comment: I recently tried tab layout. I have been successfull. But it does not fit in screen. Margens issues are not solved yet!

Comment: hmmm, i have worked on it too, and my works fine.! post question on that :D i will help :p

Comment: :D .. smart !! . Ok i can understand :p . I will post and tell you about that :D

Comment: Contact source bro :p

Comment: haan yar :D smart nai bus we also need points :p 
https://www.facebook.com/mfaisal.hyder

Comment: Han han.. i will help you in earning points ! Samjhh gaye ho na ! :p

Answer (score 1):

There's some quick tips that may solve the problem:

1) Did you make sure that yourt Custom activity is registered in the android manifest?

2) Don't call the `startActivity` directly in your fragment, use an interface to communicate with the activity that is holding your fragment and do the `startActivity` there, this way is more clean.

3) Don't use class names like `Custom` or `Tab1` use `CustomActivity` and `TabFragment`, follow the android code style guidelines.

[Code guidelines](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html)

[Communication Fragment-Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25392549/1403997)

Keep in mind that if some day, your boss or someone tells you "Well, now we're going to do a version for Tablet devices" this code is going to need a lot of changes, that's why you've to communicate your fragments with your activities, and perform the logic there.

Tell me if you have any problem, or if the issue doesn't get resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your time buddy.
i have solved my problem.
See above.
For you, i will give  +1