# When click button inside fragment I want to go to another fragment in the parent TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-tablayout

I have a MainActivity, Contains TabLayout having two fragments FA, FB

The First Fragment FA having another Tablayout contains 2 fragments FAA, FAB

I have a button inside FAA, i want when i click on it, it send me to FB which already inside the parent TabLayout

I tried many solutions but it didn't help, any suggestions?

```
    @OnClick(R.id.frag_timeline_fab_faa)
public void goToFBFromFAA(View view) {

    // Code shoud be here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is through interfaces.[Here is a similar question I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247954/communicating-between-a-fragment-and-an-activity-best-practices)

In fragment FAA:

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Param param);
}
```

Then in your parent fragment you need to implement that interface:

```
public class FA extends Fragment implements 
        FAA.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Param param) {
    //Your code here
    }
}
```