# How to validate fragment tab content just before switch to other tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

My app deals with configuration of a device.  I divided configurations into different categories.  I used fragment tabs.  Each tab contains different views such as editext, spinner, etc.  I have to validate each tab just before switch to other.  How can i do it well ?  I have co-ordinate the whole configuration from my tabactivity.

Comment: you will need to use Fragment manager for that.

Comment: go through this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJeeZHFgLfc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicating between a fragment and an activity - best practices.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247954/communicating-between-a-fragment-and-an-activity-best-practices)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html